# Unseen factor levels when appending new records with unseen string values to a dataframe, cause Warning and result in NA

Tags: r, dataframe, append, r-factor

I have a dataframe (14.5K rows by 15 columns) containing billing data from 2001 to 2007.

I append new 2008 data to it with: `alltime <- rbind(alltime,all2008)`

Unfortunately that generates a warning:

```
> Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,  :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated
```

My guess is that there are some new patients whose names were not in the previous dataframe and therefore it would not know what level to give those. Similarly new unseen names in the 'referring doctor' column.

What's the solution?

Comment: This is odd. Factor's shouldn't cause this, in help to `rbind` is stated: "Factors have their levels expanded as necessary" (R-2.9.2). Maybe you could check exactly which column causes this?

Comment: What a great point Marek! The warning message freaked me. After reading your comment I went back to explore my data. All the new data appears to be there and additional levels have been added. At this stage I could just leave it as a warning that should be ignored - which is a dangerous habit to get into (since then one has to keep a database in their head of warnings to be taken seriously vs warnings to be ignored). How do I figure out where the warning message came from?

Comment: *"The way R imports data and automatically works out what is numeric and what is not (and thereby makes it a factor)..."* see `read.csv(..., stringsAsFactors=FALSE` and `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`. There are lots of questions on SO.

Comment: "Warning" means a warning, not an error. You can check if the resulting factor is correct using str() or table(..., useNA='ifany'). It's better to give a reproducible example (you could add one in <10 lines).

Comment: Similar question [Convert data.frame columns from factors to characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters/)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It could be caused by mismatch of types in two `data.frames`.

First of all check types (classes). To diagnostic purposes do this:

```
new2old <- rbind( alltime, all2008 ) # this gives you a warning
old2new <- rbind( all2008, alltime ) # this should be without warning

cbind(
    alltime = sapply( alltime, class),
    all2008 = sapply( all2008, class),
    new2old = sapply( new2old, class),
    old2new = sapply( old2new, class)
)
```

I expect there be a row looks like:

```
            alltime  all2008   new2old  old2new
...         ...      ...       ...      ...
some_column "factor" "numeric" "factor" "character"
...         ...      ...       ...      ...
```

If so then explanation:
`rbind` don't check types match. If you analyse `rbind.data.frame` code then you could see that the first argument initialized output types. If in first data.frame type is a factor, then output data.frame column is factor with levels `unique(c(levels(x1),levels(x2)))`. But when in second data.frame column isn't factor then `levels(x2)` is `NULL`, so levels don't extend.

**It means that your output data are wrong! There are `NA`'s instead of true values**

I suppose that:

1. you create you old data with another R/RODBC version so types were created with different methods (different settings - decimal separator maybe)
2. there are NULL's or some specific data in problematic column, eg. someone change column under database.

Solution:

find wrong column and find reason why its's wrong and fixed. Eliminate cause not symptoms.

Comment: Yip. You are correct. 
in one data frame a column's class was a factor and in another it was a numeric. That messed things up badly. I converted the numeric to a factor and all was OK. Thank you for your guidance. 

There were some other discrepancies as well. For instance, factor-character discrepancy did not mess things up.

Comment: You have right about factor-character, somewhere in code I found that levels for this combination will be `unique(c(levels(x1),x2))`. One thing: combination factor-character leads to a factor, combination character-factor to character. So it's better when types match.

Answer (score 27):

An "easy" way is to simply not have your strings set as factors when importing text data.

Note that the `read.{table,csv,...}` functions take a `stringsAsFactors` parameter, which is by default set to `TRUE`. You can set this to `FALSE` while you're importing and `rbind`-ing your data.

If you'd like to set the column to be a factor at the end, you can do that too.

For example:

```
alltime <- read.table("alltime.txt", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
all2008 <- read.table("all2008.txt", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
alltime <- rbind(alltime, all2008)
# If you want the doctor column to be a factor, make it so:
alltime$doctor <- as.factor(alltime$doctor)
```

Answer (score 9):

1) create the data frame with stringsAsFactor set to FALSE. This should resolve the factor-issue

2) afterwards don't use rbind - it messes up the column names if the data frame is empty. simply do it this way:

```
df[nrow(df)+1,] <- c("d","gsgsgd",4)
```

/

```
> df <- data.frame(a = character(0), b=character(0), c=numeric(0))

> df[nrow(df)+1,] <- c("d","gsgsgd",4)

Warnmeldungen:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "d") :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "gsgsgd") :
  invalid factor level, NAs generated

> df <- data.frame(a = character(0), b=character(0), c=numeric(0), stringsAsFactors=F)

> df[nrow(df)+1,] <- c("d","gsgsgd",4)

> df
  a      b c
1 d gsgsgd 4
```

Answer (score 4):

As suggested in the previous answer, read the columns as character and do the conversion to factors after `rbind`.
`SQLFetch` (I assume *RODBC*) has also the `stringsAsFactors` or the `as.is` argument to control the conversion of characters.
Allowed values are as for `read.table`, e.g., `as.is=TRUE` or some column number.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with type mismatches, especially with factors. I had to glue together two otherwise compatible datasets.

My solution is to convert factors in both dataframes to "character". Then it works like a charm :-)

```
    convert.factors.to.strings.in.dataframe <- function(dataframe)
    {
        class.data  <- sapply(dataframe, class)
        factor.vars <- class.data[class.data == "factor"]
        for (colname in names(factor.vars))
        {
            dataframe[,colname] <- as.character(dataframe[,colname])
        }
        return (dataframe)
    }
```

If you want to see the types in your two dataframes run (change var names):

```
    cbind("orig"=sapply(allSurveyData, class), 
          "merge" = sapply(curSurveyDataMerge, class),
          "eq"=sapply(allSurveyData, class) == sapply(curSurveyDataMerge, class)
    )
```

Comment: `mydf[sapply(mydf, is.factor)] <- lapply(mydf[sapply(mydf, is.factor)], as.character)` seems like a simpler approach.

Answer (score 2):

When you create the dataframe you have the choice of making your string columns factors (`stringsAsFactors=T`), or keeping them as strings.

**For your case, don't make your string columns factors. Keep them as strings, then appending works fine.** If you need them to ultimately be factors, do all the insertion and appending first as string, then finally convert them to factor.

If you make the string columns factors and then append rows containing unseen values, you get the error you mentioned on each new unseen factor level and that value gets replaced with NA...

```
> df <- data.frame(patient=c('Ann','Bob','Carol'), referring_doctor=c('X','Y','X'), stringsAsFactors=T)

  patient referring_doctor
1     Ann                X
2     Bob                Y
3   Carol                X

> df <- rbind(df, c('Denise','Z'))
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "Denise") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = "Z") :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
> df
  patient referring_doctor
1     Ann                X
2     Bob                Y
3   Carol                X
4    <NA>             <NA>
```

So **don't make your string columns factors. Keep them as strings, then appending works fine**:

```
> df <- data.frame(patient=c('Ann','Bob','Carol'), referring_doctor=c('X','Y','X'), stringsAsFactors=F)
> df <- rbind(df, c('Denise','Z'))
  patient referring_doctor
1     Ann                X
2     Bob                Y
3   Carol                X
4  Denise                Z
```

**To change the default behavior**:

```
options(stringsAsFactors=F)
```

**To convert individual columns to/from string or factor**

```
df$col <- as.character(df$col)
df$col <- as.factor(df$col)
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a function to take the common row names of 2 data frames and do an rbind where we basically find the fields that are factors, add the new factors then do the rbind.  This should take care of any factor issues:

rbindCommonCols<-function(x, y){

```
commonColNames = intersect(colnames(x), colnames(y))
x = x[,commonColNames]
y = y[,commonColNames]

colClassesX = sapply(x, class)
colClassesY = sapply(y, class)
classMatch = paste( colClassesX, colClassesY, sep = "-" )
factorColIdx = grep("factor", classMatch)

for(n in factorColIdx){ 
    x[,n] = as.factor(x[,n])
    y[,n] = as.factor(y[,n])
}

for(n in factorColIdx){ 
    x[,n] = factor(x[,n], levels = unique(c( levels(x[,n]), levels(y[,n]) )))
    y[,n] = factor(y[,n], levels = unique(c( levels(y[,n]), levels(x[,n]) )))  
} 

res = rbind(x,y)
res
```

}