# Convert data.frame columns from factors to characters

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame. Let's call him `bob`:

```
> head(bob)
                 phenotype                         exclusion
GSM399350 3- 4- 8- 25- 44+ 11b- 11c- 19- NK1.1- Gr1- TER119-
GSM399351 3- 4- 8- 25- 44+ 11b- 11c- 19- NK1.1- Gr1- TER119-
GSM399352 3- 4- 8- 25- 44+ 11b- 11c- 19- NK1.1- Gr1- TER119-
GSM399353 3- 4- 8- 25+ 44+ 11b- 11c- 19- NK1.1- Gr1- TER119-
GSM399354 3- 4- 8- 25+ 44+ 11b- 11c- 19- NK1.1- Gr1- TER119-
GSM399355 3- 4- 8- 25+ 44+ 11b- 11c- 19- NK1.1- Gr1- TER119-
```

I'd like to concatenate the rows of this data frame (this will be another question). But look:

```
> class(bob$phenotype)
[1] "factor"
```

`Bob`'s columns are factors. So, for example:

```
> as.character(head(bob))
[1] "c(3, 3, 3, 6, 6, 6)"       "c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)"      
[3] "c(29, 29, 29, 30, 30, 30)"
```

I don't begin to understand this, but I guess these are indices into the levels of the factors of the columns (of the court of king caractacus) of `bob`? Not what I need.

Strangely I can go through the columns of `bob` by hand, and do

```
bob$phenotype <- as.character(bob$phenotype)
```

which works fine. And, after some typing, I can get a data.frame whose columns are characters rather than factors. So my question is: how can I do this automatically? How do I convert a data.frame with factor columns into a data.frame with character columns without having to manually go through each column?

Bonus question: why does the manual approach work?

Comment: would be nice if you would make the question reproducible, so include the structure of `bob`.

Answer (score 393, accepted):

Just following on Matt and Dirk.  If you want to recreate your existing data frame without changing the global option, you can recreate it with an apply statement:

```
bob <- data.frame(lapply(bob, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

This will convert all variables to class "character", if you want to only convert factors, see [Marek's solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2853231/180892).

As @hadley points out, the following is more concise.

```
bob[] <- lapply(bob, as.character)
```

In both cases, `lapply` outputs a list; however, owing to the magical properties of R, the use of `[]` in the second case keeps the data.frame class of the `bob` object, thereby eliminating the need to convert back to a data.frame using `as.data.frame` with the argument `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

Comment: Shane, that'll also turn numerical columns into character.

Comment: @Dirk: That's true, although it isn't clear whether that's a problem here.  Clearly, creating things correctly up front is the best solution.  I don't think that it's *easy* to automatically convert data types across a data frame.  One option is to use the above but then use `type.convert` after casting everything to `character`, then recast `factors` back to `character` again.

Comment: This seems to discard row names.

Comment: To better understand `lapply()` and friends, you may want to see this [useful summary](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3505701/181638)

Comment: @piccolbo did you use `bob[] <- ` in the example or `bob <- `?; the first keeps the data.frame; the second changes the data.frame to a list, dropping the rownames. I will update the answer

Comment: @david you are correct, not sure what evidence I had for my first comment

Comment: A variant that only converts factor columns to character using an anonymous function:

`iris[] <- lapply(iris, function(x) if (is.factor(x)) as.character(x) else {x})`

Comment: iris[] <- sapply(iris, function(x) if (is.factor(x)) as.character(x) else x)  Sapply also gives the same output on presence of []

Comment: How did you figure out that ```[] = lapply``` returns a dataframe

Answer (score 348):

To replace only factors:

```
i <- sapply(bob, is.factor)
bob[i] <- lapply(bob[i], as.character)
```

In package dplyr [in version 0.5.0 new function `mutate_if` was introduced](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md#dplyr-050):

```
library(dplyr)
bob %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) -> bob
```

...and [in version 1.0.0 was replaced by `across`](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md#across):

```
library(dplyr)
bob %>% mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character)) -> bob
```

[Package purrr from RStudio](http://blog.rstudio.org/2015/09/29/purrr-0-1-0/) gives another alternative:

```
library(purrr)
bob %>% modify_if(is.factor, as.character) -> bob
```

Comment: Not working for me, sadly. Don't know why. Probably because I have colnames?

Comment: @mohawkjohn Shouldn't be issue. You got error or results not as you expected?

Comment: Note: The `purrr` line returns a list, not a `data.frame`!

Comment: This also works if you already have an `i` that is a vector of `colnames()`.

Comment: @RoyalTS should be `modify_if` instead of `map_if` from the very beginning :)

Answer (score 43):

The global option

> stringsAsFactors:
>       The default setting for arguments of data.frame and read.table.

may be something you want to set to `FALSE` in your startup files (e.g. ~/.Rprofile). Please see `help(options)`.

Comment: The problem with this is that when you execute your code in an environment where that .Rprofile file is missing you'll get bugs!

Comment: I tend to call it at the beginning of scripts rather than setting is in the .Rprofile.

Answer (score 26):

If you understand how factors are stored, you can avoid using apply-based functions to accomplish this. Which isn't at all to imply that the apply solutions don't work well.

Factors are structured as numeric indices tied to a list of 'levels'. This can be seen if you convert a factor to numeric. So:

```
> fact <- as.factor(c("a","b","a","d")
> fact
[1] a b a d
Levels: a b d

> as.numeric(fact)
[1] 1 2 1 3
```

The numbers returned in the last line correspond to the levels of the factor.

```
> levels(fact)
[1] "a" "b" "d"
```

Notice that `levels()` returns an array of characters. You can use this fact to easily and compactly convert factors to strings or numerics like this:

```
> fact_character <- levels(fact)[as.numeric(fact)]
> fact_character
[1] "a" "b" "a" "d"
```

This also works for numeric values, provided you wrap your expression in `as.numeric()`.

```
> num_fact <- factor(c(1,2,3,6,5,4))
> num_fact
[1] 1 2 3 6 5 4
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6
> num_num <- as.numeric(levels(num_fact)[as.numeric(num_fact)])
> num_num
[1] 1 2 3 6 5 4
```

Comment: This answer does not address the problem, which is how do I convert *all* of the factor columns in my data frame to character.  `as.character(f)`, is better in both readability and efficiency to `levels(f)[as.numeric(f)]`. If you wanted to be clever, you could use `levels(f)[f]` instead. Note that when converting a factor with numeric values, you do get some benefit from `as.numeric(levels(f))[f]` over, e.g., `as.numeric(as.character(f))`, but this is because you only have to convert the levels to numeric and then subset. `as.character(f)` is just fine as it is.

Answer (score 22):

If you want a new data frame `bobc` where *every* factor vector in `bobf` is converted to a character vector, try this:

```
bobc <- rapply(bobf, as.character, classes="factor", how="replace")
```

If you then want to convert it back, you can create a logical vector of which columns are factors, and use that to selectively apply factor

```
f <- sapply(bobf, class) == "factor"
bobc[,f] <- lapply(bobc[,f], factor)
```

Comment: +1 for doing only what was necessary (i.e. not converting the entire data.frame to character). This solution is robust to a data.frame that contains mixed types.

Comment: This example should be in the `Examples' section for rapply, like at: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/rapply.html .  Anyone know how to request that that be so?

Comment: If you want to end up with a data frame, simple wrap the rapply in a data.frame call (using the stringsAsFactors set to FALSE argument)

Answer (score 16):

I typically make this function apart of all my projects. Quick and easy.

```
unfactorize <- function(df){
  for(i in which(sapply(df, class) == "factor")) df[[i]] = as.character(df[[i]])
  return(df)
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Another way is to convert it using apply

```
bob2 <- apply(bob,2,as.character)
```

And a better one (the previous is of class 'matrix')

```
bob2 <- as.data.frame(as.matrix(bob),stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Comment: Following @Shane's comment: in order to get data.frame, do `as.data.frame(lapply(...`

Answer (score 9):

**Update: Here's an example of something that doesn't work.  I thought it would, but I think that the stringsAsFactors option only works on character strings - it leaves the factors alone.**

Try this:

```
bob2 <- data.frame(bob, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Generally speaking, whenever you're having problems with factors that should be characters, there's a `stringsAsFactors` setting somewhere to help you (including a global setting).

Comment: This does work, if he sets it when creating `bob` to begin with (but not after the fact).

Comment: Right.  Just wanted to be clear that this doesn't solve the problem, per se - but thanks for noting that it does prevent it.

Answer (score 8):

Or you can try `transform`:

```
newbob <- transform(bob, phenotype = as.character(phenotype))
```

Just be sure to put every factor you'd like to convert to character.

Or you can do something like this and kill all the pests with one blow:

```
newbob_char <- as.data.frame(lapply(bob[sapply(bob, is.factor)], as.character), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
newbob_rest <- bob[!(sapply(bob, is.factor))]
newbob <- cbind(newbob_char, newbob_rest)
```

It's ***not*** good idea to shove the data in code like this, I could do the `sapply` part separately (actually, it's much easier to do it like that), but you get the point... I haven't checked the code, 'cause I'm not at home, so I hope it works! =)

This approach, however, has a downside... you must reorganize columns afterwards, while with `transform` you can do whatever you like, but at cost of *"pedestrian-style-code-writting"*...

So there... =)

Answer (score 7):

At the beginning of your data frame include `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to ignore all misunderstandings.

Answer (score 6):

If you would use `data.table` package for the operations on data.frame then the problem is not present.

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(col1 = c("a","b","c"), col2 = 1:3)
sapply(dt, class)
#       col1        col2 
#"character"   "integer"
```

If you have a factor columns in you dataset already and you want to convert them to character you can do the following.

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(col1 = factor(c("a","b","c")), col2 = 1:3)
sapply(dt, class)
#     col1      col2 
# "factor" "integer" 
upd.cols = sapply(dt, is.factor)
dt[, names(dt)[upd.cols] := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = upd.cols]
sapply(dt, class)
#       col1        col2 
#"character"   "integer"
```

Comment: DT circumvents the sapply fix proposed by Marek: `In [<-.data.table(*tmp*, sapply(bob, is.factor),  :
  Coerced 'character' RHS to 'double' to match the column's type. Either change the target column to 'character' first (by creating a new 'character' vector length 1234 (nrows of entire table) and assign that; i.e. 'replace' column), or coerce RHS to 'double' (e.g. 1L, NA_[real|integer]_, as.*, etc) to make your intent clear and for speed. Or, set the column type correctly up front when you create the table and stick to it, please.` It's easier to fix the DF and recreate the DT.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me - I finally figured a one liner

```
df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df,function (y) if(class(y)=="factor" ) as.character(y) else y),stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Answer (score 3):

New function "across" was introduced in dplyr [version 1.0.0](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html). The new function will supersede scoped variables (_if, _at, _all). Here's the official [documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html)

```
library(dplyr)
bob <- bob %>% 
       mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character))
```

Comment: I include this change in my answer. Thanks to bring my attention.

Comment: no problem. I tried to edit your answer but it got rejected by review team.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `convert` in `hablar` which gives readable syntax compatible with `tidyverse` pipes:

```
library(dplyr)
library(hablar)

df <- tibble(a = factor(c(1, 2, 3, 4)),
             b = factor(c(5, 6, 7, 8)))

df %>% convert(chr(a:b))
```

which gives you:

```
  a     b    
  <chr> <chr>
1 1     5    
2 2     6    
3 3     7    
4 4     8
```

Answer (score 2):

With the `dplyr`-package loaded use

```
bob=bob%>%mutate_at("phenotype", as.character)
```

if you only want to change the `phenotype`-column specifically.

Answer (score 1):

This function does the trick

```
df <- stacomirtools::killfactor(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a newer option?

```
library("tidyverse")

bob <- bob %>% group_by_if(is.factor, as.character)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works transforming all to character and then the numeric to numeric:

```
makenumcols<-function(df){
  df<-as.data.frame(df)
  df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)
  cond <- apply(df, 2, function(x) {
    x <- x[!is.na(x)]
    all(suppressWarnings(!is.na(as.numeric(x))))
  })
  numeric_cols <- names(df)[cond]
  df[,numeric_cols] <- sapply(df[,numeric_cols], as.numeric)
  return(df)
}
```

Adapted from: [Get column types of excel sheet automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42735346/get-column-types-of-excel-sheet-automatically)