# What are the restrictions for the column classes in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

**UPDATE** This problem is not relevant anymore for `data.table` versions 1.8.0 and higher. From the NEWS file:

> character columns are now allowed in keys and are preferred to
>           factor. data.table() and setkey() no longer coerce character to
>           factor. Factors are still supported. Implements FR#1493, FR#1224
>           and (partially) FR#951.

**Original question**

I try to join two data.tables. However, the success of the join is dependent on the classes of the columns I use to match the data.tables. More precisely, it seems that the columns should not have the class "character". I don't quite understand the reason, but I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here. So help is really appreciated.

Here is an example:

```
#Objective: Select all rows from DT for which Region=="US", Year >= 5 & Year<=8, Cat="A"                 
library(data.table)
#Set-up data.table DT
DT <- data.table(Year=1:20, value=rnorm(20), Region=c(rep("US", 10), rep("EU", 10)),     Cat=c(rep("A", 7), rep("B", 7), rep("C", 6)))
setkey(DT, Region, Cat, Year)
#Set-up data.table int_DT to join with DT
years   <- 5:8
df      <- data.frame(Region=c("US", "EU"), Categ=c("A", "B"))
int_DT <- J(cbind(df[1, ], years))
#Join them: Works like a charm!
DT[int_DT]

#Let's assume that for any reason the columns in df are of class "character"
df$Region <- as.character(df$Region)
df$Categ  <- as.character(df$Categ)
#Rebuild int_DT
int_DT    <- J(cbind(df[1, ], years))
DT[int_DT]    
#Error in `[.data.table`(DT, int_DT) : 
#  unsorted column Region of i is not internally type integer.

#OK, maybe the problem is that the column classes in DT are factors, so change those:
DT[, Cat:=as.character(Cat)]
DT[, Region:=as.character(Region)]

DT[int_DT]
#Error in `[.data.table`(DT, int_DT) : 
#  When i is a data.table, x must be sorted to avoid a vector scan of x per row of i
```

Still doesn't work. Why? What is the restriction? What do I miss? Additionally information: I'm using data.table 1.6.6 and R version 2.13.2 (2011-09-30) on Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit).

Comment: Why did you have the thought of changing DT's key columns to character? data.table keys work with integers (or factors) only. Assigning to DT's key dropped the key (correctly).

Comment: To answer your question, @MatthewDowle, in my real problem, I create the inner data.table i on the run and based on a data.frame with character classes. So it was the other way round (I start with character columns and get the error). However, thanks to your answer I know the way forward: just convert the columns of the data.frame before I create the data.table i.

Comment: Thanks to your question the error message has been improved in v1.7.1. See item in [latest NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable). @Andrie, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a join operation to get your desired results. You said:
*'Objective: Select all rows from DT for which Region=="US", Year >= 5 & Year<=8, Cat="A"'*

```
DT[Region=="US" & Year>=5 & Year <= 8 & Categ=="A"]
     Year       value Region Categ
[1,]    5 -0.18631697     US     A
[2,]    6  1.40059083     US     A
[3,]    7  0.01848557     US     A
```

---

But to answer your question about column classes.  I managed to get this code to work, which essentially mirrors your code above:

```
> setkey(DT, Region, Categ, Year)
> df      <- data.frame(Region=c("US", "EU"), Categ=c("A", "B"))
> dt2 <- data.table(data.frame(df[1, ], Year=5:8))
Warning message:
In data.frame(df[1, ], Year = 5:8) :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded
> dt1[dt2]
     Region Categ Year      value
[1,]     US     A    5 -0.5565422
[2,]     US     A    6 -0.1805841
[3,]     US     A    7  1.4474403
[4,]     US     A    8         NA
```

---

The same, with column classes of `character`:

```
df$Region <- as.character(df$Region)
df$Categ  <- as.character(df$Categ)
#Rebuild int_DT
dt2    <- J(cbind(df[1, ], Year=5:8))

Warning message:
In data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) :
  row names were found from a short variable and have been discarded

setkey(dt2, Region)
dt1[dt2]
   Region Year       value Categ Categ.1 Year.1
       US    1  1.20152558     A       A      5
       US    2  1.89391079     A       A      5
       US    3 -1.76022634     A       A      5
       US    4  0.92454680     A       A      5
       US    5 -0.55654217     A       A      5
       ...
       snip 
       ...
       US    9  0.67936243     B       A      8
       US   10 -0.09355764     B       A      8
```

Comment: Thanks @Andrie. Regarding your first point: The whole process should be very flexible: for instance, I do not know the number of columns I want to use for a match in advance. Therefore, your simple approach does not work for me, as far as I can see. Regarding your thoughts on the issue: 1) does not seem to be a problem; matching the column names of `DT` and `int_DT` does not help. 2) Setting the key (`setkey(int_DT, Region, Categ, Year)`) does work. This, however, let me wonder why it works for factors without setting the key?

Comment: @Christoph_J Your approach should work just fine for flexible analysis of data.  Good luck.

Comment: @Andrie Column names don't matter, that's not issue. And only x needs to have a key in joins, i can be unkeyed no problem at all. The join columns of i just need to be factor, not character.

Comment: Thanks from my side as well, @MatthewDowle. That answers my question!

Comment: Cool. @Andie could you edit your answer to remove first two (incorrect) bullets please. Just to tidy up the accepted answer.

Comment: @MatthewDowle Feel free to edit the answer to reflect an answer you feel comfortable with.

Comment: @Andrie I don't have the 2,000 rep needed to edit your answer. I tried yesterday actually (a very gently edit) and got the message that it went to moderation. Don't know who that is, how long it takes, or if the edit was rejected.