# Reclassify select columns in Data Table

Tags: r, data.table

I wish to change the class of selected variables in a data table, using a vectorized operation. I am new to the data.table syntax, and am trying to learn as much as possible. I now the question is basic, but it will help me to better understand the data table way of thinking!

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813578/convert-column-classes-in-data-table?rq=1)! However, the solution seems to pertain to either reclassing just one column or all columns. My question is unique to a select few columns.

```
### Load package
require(data.table)

### Create pseudo data
data <- data.table(id     = 1:10,
                   height = rnorm(10, mean = 182, sd = 20),
                   weight = rnorm(10, mean = 160, sd = 10),
                   color  = rep(c('blue', 'gold'), times = 5))

### Reclass all columns
data <- data[, lapply(.SD, as.character)]

### Search for columns to be reclassed
index <- grep('(id)|(height)|(weight)', names(data))

### data frame method
df <- data.frame(data)
df[, index] <- lapply(df[, index], as.numeric)

### Failed attempt to reclass columns used the data.table method
data <- data[, lapply(index, as.character), with = F]
```

Any help would be appreciated. My data are large and so using regular expressions to create a vector of column numbers to reclassify is necessary.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that @SimonO101 did most of the Job

```
data[, names(data)[index] := lapply(.SD, as.character) , .SDcols = index ]
```

You can just use the `:=` magic

Comment: +1 that's it!! Ok, since my answer is incorrect I'm going to delete it.

Comment: (+1) you can directly pass `index` as well. `data[, c(index) := lapply(.SD, as.character) , .SDcols = index ]`

Comment: Alternatively, without using `.SDcols`: `data[, c(index) := lapply(data[, 1:3, with=FALSE], as.character)]`

Comment: strangely, i copy/pasted this solution, which ran successfully, but didn't actually change the named columns in my `index`... @mnel's answer below did the trick for me.

Answer (score 9):

You could avoid the overhead of the construction of `.SD` within `j` by using `set`

```
for(j in index) set(data, j =j ,value = as.character(data[[j]]))
```

Comment: (+1) This is fast/efficient on 2 accounts: 1) no .SD and 2) using `set` instead of `:=` (the latter of which has the `[.data.table` overhead). Brilliant!

Answer (score 4):

You just need to use `.SDcols` with your index vector (I learnt that today!), but that will *just* return a data table with the reclassed columns. @dickoa 's answer is what you are looking for.

```
data <- data[, lapply(.SD, as.character) , .SDcols = index ]
sapply(data , class)
        id      height      weight 
"character" "character" "character"
```

Comment: This creates a new data table with only the "index" columns. How can I change the class of the "index" columns, and keep the rest of the data.table in tact? I can easily see how to do this using a merge or cbind, but there has got to be a more elegant way!

Comment: Argggh. You are right. I know this, but I also have trouble with the syntax. There is an easy way - trying to remember the correct syntax!!

Comment: This is important to note. Thank you for editing your response to reflect what we learned!