# Difference between large number of rows

Tags: r, data.table

I have a matrix with very large number of rows and only two paired columns. I want to calculate the differences between each rows in column 1 and if the difference is less than a predefined value(.001) then calculate the average of those rows in both columns. For example I have a matrix called weights,

```
  A      B
185.0765 10
185.3171 20
186.0777 30
186.0780 40
188.0078 50

weights<-as.data.table(weights)
bins<-weights[A %between% c(A[3],(A[3]+.001))]
meanA<-mean(bins$A)
meanB<-mean(bins$B)
```

and the resulting matrix will be,

```
  A      B
185.0765 10
185.3171 20
186.0779 35
188.0078 50
```

I would be thankful if someone could please advice me how to do this for large number of rows. I think using a for loop would not be very efficient.

Comment: +1 for input data and desired output and interesting problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should achieve what you want to do, using `data.table`:

```
DT <- data.table( weights )
DT[ , Group :=( cumsum( c( 1 , ifelse( diff(weights$A) < 0.001 , 0 , 1 ) ) ) ) ]
DT[ , lapply(.SD, mean) , by=Group ,  .SDcols = c("A","B") ]
#   Group        A  B
#1:     1 185.0765 10
#2:     2 185.3171 20
#3:     3 186.0779 35
#4:     4 188.0078 50
```

The idea is we use a cumulative sum to find the groups of `A` that have a difference of < 0.001. If the difference is under this threshold we put a `0` in our `Group` column, so in the cumulative sum it will be part of the same group.

As suggested by **@eddi** a more succinct and efficient way of doing this would be to do the grouping and the calculation all at the same time, in one call:

```
DT <- data.table( weights )
DT[ , lapply(.SD, mean) , by = list(Group = cumsum(c(1,diff(A)) >= 0.001)) ,  .SDcols = c("A","B") ]
```

As an aside, it is always helpful to have an absolute number of rows. A *very large number* of rows mean different things to different people and use-cases. Are we talking million? Hundreds of millions?

Comment: +1 That's ideal use of `.SD` since it's using all the information in `.SD`. The main inefficiency of using `.SD` is if taking a subset of rows from it; e.g., `head(.SD,2)` wastefully creates all of `.SD` even though only the first 2 rows are needed. But `lapply` through `.SD` uses all the data, and is what `.SD` is there for, especially with `.SDcols`, too.

Comment: @MatthewDowle ah ok, I think I am slowly beginning to understand `.SD` and the wonderful `data.table` package! (thanks and a hat-tip!)

Comment: using `by = list(Group = cumsum(c(1,diff(A)) >= 0.001))` would achieve the exact same output in less lines and without using `ifelse`

Comment: @MatthewDowle is it intended behavior for `A` to be dropped from `.SD` when it's used in `by`, even when `by` is not just a simple list that includes `A`?

Comment: @eddi thanks, that is a really good point (and a much more elegant/efficient way to do the grouping). do you mind if I add that to the answer? Sometimes I prefer more lines if it aids clarity, but in this case it doesn't.

Comment: @SimonO101 not at all, please do

Comment: and as a side note, please take any and all code I post and use it as you like, there is no need to ask me :)

Comment: @eddi Yes that's intended: any symbols used in `by` are excluded from `.SD` as most often that's what is needed; e.g., `by=month(date)`. But can force them into `.SD` using `.SDcols` if needed.

Comment: @eddi, IIUC, I had the [same question](http://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/datatable-help/2013-May/001760.html) as well on the data.table mailing list: