# Update class of a subset of columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to change a couple of data.table columns from factor to character

```
library(data.table)

ir <- as.data.table(iris)
ir[, Species2 := Species]
```

I can identify which columns I need to change

```
facs <- which(sapply(ir, is.factor))
facs
```

And I can update the columns by name:

```
ir[, c("Species", "Species2") := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = facs]
sapply(ir, class)
```

Is there a way to update the columns without referencing them by name?

Comment: Here, you changed the class by finding which columns are factor.  I didn't understand how you want the result

Comment: I've got the result I want, but it relies on me knowing the names of the columns which are factors when I use `:=`. Is there a programatic way to replace `c("Species", "Species2")`

Comment: You can use the numeric index `5:6 := `

Comment: Parentheses work here `ir[,(facs):=lapply(.SD,as.character),.SDcols=facs]`. Also, `set`.

Comment: Perfect - data.table gets better and better!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elegantly assigning multiple columns in data.table with lapply()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943939/elegantly-assigning-multiple-columns-in-data-table-with-lapply)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close. As @akrun mentioned in a comment, you can reference the columns by index, which you've obtained using `which`.

```
ir[, which(sapply(ir, is.factor)) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = facs]
```

Or even better, as @Frank mentioned in a comment, you can use parentheses.

```
ir[, (fac) := lapply(.SD, as.character), .SDcols = fac]
```

Now if you look at `str(ir)`, you'll see that `Species` and `Species2` are now `chr` rather than `factor`.

Comment: @EdG: Glad I could help. Many thanks to akrun and Frank as well.

Comment: @Akrun - apologies if the question wasn't clear enough.