# Convert *some* column classes in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to convert a subset of data.table cols to a new class. There's a popular question here ([Convert column classes in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813578/convert-column-classes-in-data-table)) but the answer creates a new object, rather than operating on the starter object.

Take this example:

```
dat <- data.frame(ID=c(rep("A", 5), rep("B",5)), Quarter=c(1:5, 1:5), value=rnorm(10))
cols <- c('ID', 'Quarter')
```

How best to convert to just the `cols` columns to (e.g.) a factor? In a normal data.frame you could do this:

```
dat[, cols] <- lapply(dat[, cols], factor)
```

but that doesn't work for a data.table, and neither does this

```
dat[, .SD := lapply(.SD, factor), .SDcols = cols]
```

A comment in the linked question from Matt Dowle (from Dec 2013) suggests the following, which works fine, but seems a bit less elegant.

```
for (j in cols) set(dat, j = j, value = factor(dat[[j]]))
```

Is there currently a better data.table answer (i.e. shorter + doesn't generate a counter variable), or should I just use the above + `rm(j)`?

Comment: I believe method Matt Dowle recommends would be best.  He is, after all, the *data.table* author.

Comment: True, but the comment was from 2013 and there have been many package updates since then, so I thought it worth throwing this fishing line out

Comment: More detail on the `for(...) set(...)` idiom added recently here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33000778/403310

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Besides using the option as suggested by Matt Dowle, another way of changing the column classes is as follows:

```
dat[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, factor), .SDcols = cols]
```

By using the `:=` operator you update the datatable by reference. A check whether this worked:

```
> sapply(dat,class)
       ID   Quarter     value 
 "factor"  "factor" "numeric"
```

As suggeted by @MattDowle in the comments, you can also use a combination of `for(...) set(...)` as follows:

```
for (col in cols) set(dat, j = col, value = factor(dat[[col]]))
```

which will give the same result. A third alternative is:

```
for (col in cols) dat[, (col) := factor(dat[[col]])]
```

On a smaller datasets, the `for(...) set(...)` option is about three times faster than the `lapply` option (but that doesn't really matter, because it is a small dataset). On larger datasets (e.g. 2 million rows), each of these approaches takes about the same amount of time. For testing on a larger dataset, I used:

```
dat <- data.table(ID=c(rep("A", 1e6), rep("B",1e6)),
                  Quarter=c(1:1e6, 1:1e6),
                  value=rnorm(10))
```

---

Sometimes, you will have to do it a bit differently (for example when numeric values are stored as a factor). Then you have to use something like this:

```
dat[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) as.integer(as.character(x))), .SDcols = cols]
```

---

---

***WARNING:*** *The following explanation is **not** the `data.table`-way of doing things. The datatable is not updated by reference because a copy is made and stored in memory (as pointed out by @Frank), which increases memory usage. It is more an addition in order to explain the working of `with = FALSE`.*

When you want to change the column classes the same way as you would do with a dataframe, you have to add `with = FALSE` as follows:

```
dat[, cols] <- lapply(dat[, cols, with = FALSE], factor)
```

A check whether this worked:

```
> sapply(dat,class)
       ID   Quarter     value 
 "factor"  "factor" "numeric"
```

If you don't add `with = FALSE`, datatable will evaluate `dat[, cols]` as a vector. Check the difference in output between `dat[, cols]` and `dat[, cols, with = FALSE]`:

```
> dat[, cols]
[1] "ID"      "Quarter"

> dat[, cols, with = FALSE]
    ID Quarter
 1:  A       1
 2:  A       2
 3:  A       3
 4:  A       4
 5:  A       5
 6:  B       1
 7:  B       2
 8:  B       3
 9:  B       4
10:  B       5
```

Comment: I think you don't want to use `<-`. If I run `address()` before and after it, it looks like the modification is not by reference (even though `[<-.data.table` does seem to cover this usage).

Comment: @Frank I know, but I added the second part primarily to explain why you need `with=FALSE` when you want a datatable to return the columns the same way as a dataframe. I added a warning.

Comment: Yeah, I know how `with` works, but that's not the `data.table` native way, as you point out. Thanks for the main answer

Comment: Just using `lapply` on the RHS of `:=` can be the memory inefficiency, not really `:=` itself.   More details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33000778/403310) on why `for(...)set(...)` uses least memory.   In this case though, the call to `factor()` on each column may dominate.

Comment: @MattDowle Thanx. Added to my answer (with a remark about performance as well).

Comment: @Frank Added a `set` alternative.

Comment: @Jaap  New edit is good other than it's not just about speed but peak memory usage as well.   For larger datasets it can make a difference between working or not working (out-of-memory error with the `:=lapply` way). Thanks to these questions and comments, I filed an issue to optimize this so the user doesn't need to know these differences, [#1441](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1441).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.SDcols`:

`dat[, cols] <- dat[, lapply(.SD, factor), .SDcols=cols]`

Comment: Any reason this is getting downvotes? It seems to get the result the asker is looking for

Comment: Same as my comment on the other answer. One big advantage of using a data.table is modification by reference, but as far as I can tell, `[<-` with one fails to take advantage of that.

Comment: @Chris people here take the "no short answers" guideline a little too seriously. Although there's almost always room to expand/expound.