# Refer to columns in R data.table in expressions that do not update by reference

Tags: r, group-by, data.table

I am using `data.table` v. 1.12.8. I am trying to refer to columns with variables, using `()` and `get()`. It fails, and I cannot understand why. This kind of syntax does work when using `:=` and updating by reference (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42116455/how-to-loop-through-a-datatable-columns) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32940580/convert-some-column-classes-in-data-table/32942319#32942319) question).

```r
library(data.table)
X <- data.table(id = 1:5, group = c(1,1,2,2,2), v1 = c(10,12,14,16,18), type_v1 = c("t1","t2","t1","t1","t2"))
this_var <- "v1"
X[, .("v1" = sum(v1)), by = group] # this works
X[, .((this_var) = sum(get(this_var))), by = group] # this does not
```

I know that for my example, I could just use `.SD`, but my use requires referring to columns dynamically and individually, without updating the original data.table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wouldn't work on the lhs.  We can use `setNames`

```
X[, setNames(.(sum(get(this_var))), this_var), by = group]
```

Or `setnames` after that

```
setnames(X[,  sum(.SD[[1]]), by = group, .SDcols = this_var], 'V1', this_var)[]
```

-output

```
#   group v1
#1:     1 22
#2:     2 48
```

Comment: Interesting. Is there some reasoning behind why data.table treats LHS differently depending on whether it's a `:=` or a `=` expression, and so setNames has to be used in the latter case?

Comment: @roussanoff Generally the `=` would evaluate the name literally instead of the value stored in that object.