# Is there an optimal way to create a bunch of new columns with data.table?

Tags: r, data.table

I am using data.table
I have a vector of the names for the new columns. I want to create these new columns but using the information from the old columns.
Let me show it on a following example:

```
data <- data.table(a = c("OneA", "TwoB", "ThreeC"),
                   b = c(1, 2, 3))

newCols <- c("One", "Two", "Three")

for (newCol in newCols) {
  data[, eval(newCol) := gsub(paste0("^.*", newCol), "", a)]
}
```

As an output I expect (and get) the following:

```
> data
        a   b    One    Two Three
1:   OneA   1      A   OneA  OneA
2:   TwoB   2   TwoB      B  TwoB
3: ThreeC   3 ThreeC ThreeC     C
```

In this case I combine defining new columns from the vector and using the vector values themselves to fill these columns. Is there a way to do it more optimal (for example with a set())?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you where quite close. Just adapt your code to:

```
for (newCol in newCols) {
  DT[, (newCol) := sub(newCol, "", a)]
}
```

and you have a solution that is both fast and memory efficient (better than using `lapply`).

Alternatively you can also use `set` inside the for-loop:

```
for (newCol in newCols) {
  set(DT, j = newCol, value = sub(newCol, "", DT[["a"]]))
}
```

So why is a `for`-loop a better choice in this situation?

1. With `lapply` the RHS (right hand sight) of `:=` is evaluated first. This means that all the new columns are created first and have to be allocated and populated in memory first and are then added to the `data.table`. The `for`-loop approach is more efficient because it does one column at a time and thus only needs working memory for that one column.
2. `set` is a low-overhead loop-able version of `:=`. It is particularly useful for repetitively updating rows of certain columns by reference (using a for-loop). `set` eliminates the small overhead of the `[data.table`-method and is as a result therefore faster.

Above explanation is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33000778/2204410) by Matt Dowle (creator of [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table)) and the help-file `?set`.

Comment: Thank you! So far this is the fastest solution which works for me

Comment: @gdol I've added an explanation why a for-loop is a good/better choice

Comment: @Jaap Long time no speak. How have you been? This is a great reminder to confirm the difference between the two approaches. I gotta refresh my memories. 
dank je.

Answer (score 6):

One possible approach could be:

```r
library(data.table)

DT[, (newCols) := lapply(newCols, function(x) sub(x, "", a))][]
#>         a b    One    Two Three
#> 1:   OneA 1      A   OneA  OneA
#> 2:   TwoB 2   TwoB      B  TwoB
#> 3: ThreeC 3 ThreeC ThreeC     C
```

**Data**

```r
DT <- data.table(a = c("OneA", "TwoB", "ThreeC"), b = c(1, 2, 3))
newCols <- c("One", "Two", "Three")
```

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution of using `Map()`+`cbind()`

```
data <- as.data.table(c(data,`names<-`(Map(function(x) gsub(x,"",data$a),newCols),newCols)))
```

such that

```
> data
        a b    One    Two Three
1:   OneA 1      A   OneA  OneA
2:   TwoB 2   TwoB      B  TwoB
3: ThreeC 3 ThreeC ThreeC     C
```