# data.table lapply dynamic column names

Tags: r, loops, data.table, lapply

I have the below table

```
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(fruit = c('a', 'na')
                 , price_1 = c('na', 2)
                 , price_2 =  c(2, 'na')
                 ); df

   fruit price_1 price_2
1:     a      na       2
2:    na       2      na
```

I wish to cast values, in specific columns, where they are a string `na` to the logical value `NA`.
I have tried:

```
x <- c('fruit', 'price_1')

lapply(x, \(i) df[get(i) == 'na', get(i) := NA ] )
```

but I get the error:

```
Error in get(i) : object 'fruit' not found
```

What am I doing wrong? I am looking for a `data.table` method please. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, just stumbled across https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943939/elegantly-assigning-multiple-columns-in-data-table-with-lapply?rq=1

a solution is `lapply(x, \(i) df[get(i) == 'na', (i) := NA ] )`

but welcome any other methods

Comment: Use `lapply`, `.SD` and `.SDcols`; `df[ , (x) := lapply(.SD, function(v) replace(v, v == "na", NA)), .SDcols = x]`. See examples in `?":="`; "## using lapply & .SD"

Comment: See also the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html); e) Multiple columns and `:=`.

Comment: Yes, I have used `(x) :=` before. But when confronted with a different problem, this didn't immediately ring any bell
Thank you @Henrik and for the vignette link too

Comment: Great to hear that it worked the way you wanted! Cheers