# do.call (namespace:base) and rbindlist (namespace:data.table) are NOT the same

Tags: r, data.table

How can I get do.call (namespace:base) and rbindlist (namespace:data.table) to behave the same. rbindlist eliminates factor levels while do.call does not. The following shows the issue

```
(dataList <- list(data.frame(f1=rep(c("a"), each=1),"c"=rnorm(2),"d"=rnorm(2)),
                      data.frame(f1=rep(c("b"), each=1),"c"=rnorm(2),"d"=rnorm(2))) )

(rbindlist.Data <- rbindlist(dataList)) # combines lists into ONE data.frame same as above
(do.call.Data <- do.call(rbind, dataList))
```

Answer (score 7):

This behaviour has been fixed in version 1.8.9 of `data.table`. You can download the latest version from [R-forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/datatable/) or wait for 1.9.0 to hit CRAN.

From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable) :

> BUG FIXES
>
> - rbindlist() now binds factor columns correctly, [#2650](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=240&atid=975&func=detail&aid=2650).

Answer (score 4):

It's true that `rbindlist` doesn't deal well with factors.

Notice that the internal representation of "a" in `dataList[[1]]$f1` and the internal representation of "b" in `dataList[[2]]$f1` are both `1`; verify this using `str(dataList)`. Unfortunately, `rbindlist` will combine the internal representations; verify this using `str(rbindlist.Data)`.

**The solution is to `rbindlist` character columns, and not factor columns**, unless you're sure the factor columns use exactly the same factor representation (with the same levels and labels). One way to do this is to use `data.table` consistently:

```
(dataList <- list(data.table(f1=rep(c("a"), each=1),"c"=rnorm(2),"d"=rnorm(2)),
                  data.table(f1=rep(c("b"), each=1),"c"=rnorm(2),"d"=rnorm(2))) )
(rbindlist.Data <- rbindlist(dataList))
```

produces the desired result, because `data.table` won't convert strings to factors.

You could use your original code with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` (either in the `data.frame` call or using `options`). I wouldn't recommend this, though, as there's no harm (and much benefit) in using `data.table` from the beginning.

If you aren't making the `data.frame` yourself, you'll have to convert the column types. It's not hard with a `data.table` call; see [Convert column classes in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7813913/2596586).