# Joining a POSIXct column to Date column using data.table in R

Tags: r, date, join, data.table, posixct

In the following example, can someone explain to me why the date 2015-03-31 changed to 1034-04-03?

```
dt1 = data.table(id = c(1,2), date = as.POSIXct("2015-03-31 BST"), key = "id")
dt1
#    id       date
# 1:  1 2015-03-31
# 2:  2 2015-03-31
dt2 = data.table(id = c(1,2), date = as.Date(NA), key = "id")
dt2
#    id date
# 1:  1 <NA>
# 2:  2 <NA>
dt2[dt1, date := i.date]
dt2
#    id       date
# 1:  1 1034-04-03
# 2:  2 1034-04-03
```

My aim is to get `date` from `dt1` to `dt2` in `Date` format instead of `POSIXct` by `id` (different `id` would have different `date`). How would I do that?

Following is what I want:

```
dt2
#    id       date
# 1:  1 2015-03-31
# 2:  2 2015-03-31
```

---

**EDIT**:

I've tried the following:

```
dt2[dt1, date := as.Date(i.date)]
dt2
#    id       date
# 1:  1 2015-03-30
# 2:  2 2015-03-30
```

Unfortunately, it is giving me 2015-03-30 instead of 2015-03-31...??? How to get 2015-03-31 instead?

Comment: Can you dput the sample data?

Comment: Your code probably should give at least a warning. Please [file a bug report](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues).

Comment: Chengcj, @Roland, filed [#1200](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1200).

Comment: regarding your second question, you need to supply a timezone to as.Date().

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
dt2[dt1, date:=as.Date(i.date)]
```

You might want to also see the question [Convert column classes in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813578/convert-column-classes-in-data-table) about changing data types in data.tables.

Comment: Unfortunately, if I do what you have proposed, I get 2015-03-30 instead of 2015-03-31.... How come?

Comment: @chengcj That's very likely a timezone issue. Pass your timezone to `as.Date`.