# Change stringsAsFactors settings for data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, default, r-factor

I have a function in which I define a `data.frame` that I use loops to fill with data. At some point I get the Warning message:

> Warning messages:
> 1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, iseq, value = "CHANGE") :
> invalid factor level, NAs generated

Therefore, when I define my data.frame, I'd like to set the option `stringsAsFactors` to `FALSE` but I don't understand how to do it.

I have tried:

```
DataFrame = data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

And also:

```
options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

What is the correct way to set the stringsAsFactors option?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/r-convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters

Comment: Additional information for people searching about stringsAsFactors. Since R ver 4.0 release, stringsAsFactors is set FALSE by default. The [R blog article](https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/02/16/stringsasfactors/index.html) talks about the historical detail. Also, see [manual of data.frame](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.frame.html).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It depends on how you fill your data frame, for which you haven't given any code. When you construct a new data frame, you can do it like this:

```
x <- data.frame(aName = aVector, bName = bVector, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

In this case, *if* e.g. `aVector` is a character vector, then the dataframe column `x$aName` will be a character vector as well, and not a factor vector. Combining that with an existing data frame (using `rbind`, `cbind` or similar) should preserve that mode.

When you execute

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

you change the global default setting. So every data frame you create after executing that line will not auto-convert to factors unless explicitly told to do so. If you only need to avoid conversion in a single place, then I'd rather not change the default. However if this affects many places in your code, changing the default seems like a good idea.

One more thing: if your vector *already* contains factors, then neither of the above will change it back into a character vector. To do so, you should explicitly convert it back using `as.character` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the 'one more thing' it seems my error comes from that.