# Reading in Data.Frames with Strings as factors = False in R using chain operator

Tags: r, dataframe, chaining, rvest

I have a table source that reads into a data frame.  I know that by default, external sources are read into data frames as factors.  I'd like to apply `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the data frame call below, but it throws an error when I do this.  Can I still use chaining and turn `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`?

```
library(rvest)
pvbData <- read_html(pvbURL)
pvbDF <- pvbData %>%
html_nodes(xpath = `//*[@id="ajax_result_table"]`) %>% 
html_table() %>% 
data.frame()

data.frame(,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)  <- Throws an error
```

I know this is probably something very simple, but I'm having trouble finding a way to make this work.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though the statement should logically be `data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` if you are applying chaining, even this statement doesn't produce the required output.

The reason is misunderstanding of use of `stringsAsFactors` option. This option works only if you make the data.frame column by column. Example:

```
a <- data.frame(x = c('a','b'),y=c(1,2),stringsAsFactors = T)
str(a)

'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 2
 $ y: num  1 2

a <- data.frame(x = c('a','b'),y=c(1,2),stringsAsFactors = F)
str(a)

'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x: chr  "a" "b"
 $ y: num  1 2
```

If you give data.frame as input, stringsAsFactors option doesn't work

Solution:

Store the chaining result to a variable like this:

```
library(rvest)
pvbData <- read_html(pvbURL)
pvbDF <- pvbData %>%
html_nodes(xpath = `//*[@id="ajax_result_table"]`) %>% 
html_table()
```

And then apply this command:

```
data.frame(as.list(pvbDF),stringsAsFactors=F)
```

## Update:

If the column is already a factor, then you can't convert it to character vector using this command. Better first as.character it and retry.

You may refer to [Change stringsAsFactors settings for data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11538532/change-stringsasfactors-settings-for-data-frame) for more details.