# Removing Whitespace From a Whole Data Frame in R

Tags: r, replace, whitespace, gsub

I've been trying to remove the white space that I have in a data frame **(using R)**. The data frame is large (>1gb) and has multiple columns that contains white space in every data entry.

Is there a quick way to remove the white space from the whole data frame? I've been trying to do this on a subset of the first 10 rows of data using:

```
gsub( " ", "", mydata)
```

This didn't seem to work, although R returned an output which I have been unable to interpret.

```
str_replace( " ", "", mydata)
```

R returned **47 warnings** and did not remove the white space.

```
erase_all(mydata, " ")
```

R returned an error saying 'Error: could not find function "erase_all"'

I would really appreciate some help with this as I've spent the last 24hrs trying to tackle this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: `mydata[mydata == " "] <- ""` finds all `" "` and replaces with `""` in a `data.frame`. Is it, simply, something like this that you want?

Comment: you should add  the first lines of your file/data to the question.

Comment: I have a character column with this format : "A _ b" which I need to convert to "A_b" but those methods does not seem to work. @PKumar

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If i understood you correctly then you want to remove all the white spaces from entire data frame, i guess the code which you are using is good for removing spaces in the column names.I think you should try this:

```
 apply(myData, 2, function(x)gsub('\\s+', '',x))
```

Hope this works.

This will return a matrix however, if you want to change it to data frame then do:

```
as.data.frame(apply(myData, 2, function(x) gsub('\\s+', '', x)))
```

**EDIT In 2020:**

Using `lapply` and `trimws` function with `both=TRUE` can remove leading and trailing spaces but not inside it.Since there was no input data provided by OP, I am adding a dummy example to produce the results.

**DATA:**

```
df <- data.frame(val = c(" abc", " kl m", "dfsd "),
                 val1 = c("klm ", "gdfs", "123"),
                 num = 1:3,
                 num1 = 2:4,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**#situation: 1** (Using Base R), when we want to remove spaces **only at the leading and trailing ends NOT inside** the string values, we can use **trimws**

```
cols_to_be_rectified <- names(df)[vapply(df, is.character, logical(1))]
df[, cols_to_be_rectified] <- lapply(df[, cols_to_be_rectified], trimws)
```

**# situation: 2** (Using Base R) , when we want to remove spaces at every place in the dataframe in character columns (**inside of a string as well as at the leading and trailing ends**).

(*This was the initial solution proposed using apply, please note a solution using apply seems to work but would be very slow, also the with the question its apparently not very clear if OP really wanted to remove leading/trailing blank or every blank in the data*)

```
cols_to_be_rectified <- names(df)[vapply(df, is.character, logical(1))]
df[, cols_to_be_rectified] <- lapply(df[, cols_to_be_rectified],
                                     function(x) gsub('\\s+', '', x))
```

**## situation: 1** (Using data.table, removing only leading and trailing blanks)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
cols_to_be_rectified <- names(df)[vapply(df, is.character, logical(1))]
df[, c(cols_to_be_rectified) := lapply(.SD, trimws), .SDcols = cols_to_be_rectified]
```

**Output** from **situation1**:

> ```
>     val val1 num num1
> 1:  abc  klm   1    2
> 2: kl m gdfs   2    3
> 3: dfsd  123   3    4
> ```

**## situation: 2** (Using data.table, removing every blank inside as well as leading/trailing blanks)

```
cols_to_be_rectified <- names(df)[vapply(df, is.character, logical(1))]
df[, c(cols_to_be_rectified) := lapply(.SD, function(x) gsub('\\s+', '', x)), .SDcols = cols_to_be_rectified]
```

**Output** from **situation2**:

> ```
>     val val1 num num1
> 1:  abc  klm   1    2
> 2:  klm gdfs   2    3
> 3: dfsd  123   3    4
> ```

Note the difference between the outputs of both situation, In row number 2: you can see that, with `trimws` we can remove leading and trailing blanks, but with regex solution we are able to remove every blank(s).

I hope this helps , Thanks

Comment: Thanks Pradeep! 

So that seemed to work when I ran it on the first few rows. When I then tried to run it on the whole data set, my laptop gave up after some time and R said it had reached its memory limit. What's the best way for me to break the analysis down into smaller chunks? Can I specify that it only does the gsub function for an individual column in the data matrix one at a time?

Comment: Probably best to get the package `ff` in the first place for a data file that large.  Then you can implicitly break your file into pieces and avoid memory limits.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft you can see my answer using ff and sed.

Comment: @Pradeep Your solution only works for dataframes where every column is "character". If not, all non-character columns are transformed to "character"

Comment: @MarkusN , Please understand the question, it says "multiple columns that contains white space in every data entry" which means every element of the dataframe is character. Hence on basis on this assumption ,I have proposed this solution.This solution is working well on this question. I have never written that it will work on every situation. Please see the situation before downvoting any answer. This answer is not wrong/bad in any sense. Please also read the downvoting criteria. Please also understand this was asked long back when R version < 3.2 doesn't have function called "timws"

Comment: @PKumar, how would you address data frame with headers such as "Total students", "current intake". Space is between words and it should not be removed

Comment: I tried the solution regarding situation 2, but I don't understand what it produce - I get an error trying to adopt it.

I has an df, where one col. that is chr i want to convert to number -> Problem, values like "1 000" gets dropped, so I need to get rid of spaces in the middle before running as.integer on that col.

Several post online is related to get rid of space of an vector object, however how do you do if you have and df and just want to do it on 1 col.? 

Thanks for any clarification on this.

Comment: Found this one with stringr-package which worked fine:
```df <- as.data.frame(apply(df, 2, str_remove_all, " "))```

Answer (score 70):

A lot of the answers are older, so here in 2019 is a simple `dplyr` solution that will operate only on the character columns to remove trailing and leading whitespace.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data %>%
  mutate_if(is.character, str_trim)

## ===== 2020 edit for dplyr (>= 1.0.0) =====
df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), str_trim))
```

You can switch out the `str_trim()` function for other ones if you want a different flavor of whitespace removal.

```r
# for example, remove all spaces
df %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.character), str_remove_all, pattern = fixed(" ")))
```

Comment: How would you also convert factors to strings?

Comment: Very similar. Check out `?is.factor` and `?as.character`. The second answer here shows it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters

Comment: mutate(across(where(is.character), str_remove_all, pattern = fixed(" "))) throws an error. I believe the idea is correct, but the syntax is off.

Comment: @NewBee that is interesting. It works for me. I know aligning all the tidyverse package versions can sometimes be the problem.

Answer (score 13):

One possibility involving just `dplyr` could be:

```
data %>%
 mutate_if(is.character, trimws)
```

Or considering that all variables are of class character:

```
data %>%
 mutate_all(trimws)
```

Since `dplyr 1.0.0` (only strings):

```
data %>%
 mutate(across(where(is.character), trimws))
```

Or if all columns are strings:

```
data %>%
 mutate(across(everything(), trimws))
```

Answer (score 10):

Picking up on Fremzy and the comment from Stamper, this is now my handy routine for cleaning up whitespace in data:

```
df <- data.frame(lapply(df, trimws), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

As others have noted this changes all types to character. In my work, I first determine the types available in the original and conversions required. After trimming, I re-apply the types needed.

If your original types are OK, apply the solution from MarkusN below https://stackoverflow.com/a/37815274/2200542

Those working with Excel files may wish to explore the readxl package which defaults to trim_ws = TRUE when reading.

Comment: I have tried this solution but it changes all columns to factor.

Comment: Use `df <- data.frame(lapply(df, trimws), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.  (I know this thread is old, just noting it here for others.)

Comment: This solution worked for me - and did NOT convert the class of the columns into factors.

Answer (score 6):

Picking up on Fremzy and Mielniczuk, I came to the following solution:

```
data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) if(class(x)=="character") trimws(x) else(x)), stringsAsFactors=F)
```

It works for mixed numeric/charactert dataframes manipulates only character-columns.

Comment: changes all spaces inside names of columns

Comment: Function data.frame() checks and "corrects" columnnames by default. If you want your columnnames untouched, use data.frame(... , check.names=F)

Comment: This only trims whitespace, it doesn't remove internal whitespace, right?

Answer (score 5):

You could use trimws function in R 3.2 on all the columns.

`myData[,c(1)]=trimws(myData[,c(1)])`

You can loop this for all the columns in your dataset. It has good performance with large datasets as well.

Answer (score 4):

If you're dealing with large data sets like this, you could really benefit form the speed of `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)

for (j in names(df)) set(df, j = j, value = df[[trimws(j)]])
```

I would expect this to be the fastest solution. This line of code uses the `set` operator of `data.table`, which loops over columns really fast. There is a nice explanation here: [Fast looping with set](http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/#fast-looping-with-set).

Comment: There is a typo in this solution,the following will work: for (j in names(dat)) {
      if(class(dat[[j]])=="character") set(dat, j = j, value = trimws(dat[[j]]) )
    }

Comment: Another option (though I do not know about the speed), could be `df <- df[, lapply(.SD, trimws)]`. On Linux, I had to use an even stronger definition for `whitespace`: `df <- df[, lapply(.SD, trimws, whitespace = "[ \\t\\r\\n\\h\\v]")]`

Answer (score 3):

R is simply not the right tool for such file size. However have 2 options :

#### Use ffdply and ff base

Use `ff` and `ffbase` packages:

```
library(ff)
library(ffabse)
x <- read.csv.ffdf(file=your_file,header=TRUE, VERBOSE=TRUE,
                 first.rows=1e4, next.rows=5e4)
x$split = as.ff(rep(seq(splits),each=nrow(x)/splits))
ffdfdply( x, x$split , BATCHBYTES=0,function(myData)        
             apply(myData,2,function(x)gsub('\\s+', '',x))
```

#### Use sed (my preference)

```
sed -ir "s/(\S)\s+(/S)/\1\2/g;s/^\s+//;s/\s+$//" your_file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maintain the variable classes in your `data.frame` - you should know that using `apply` will clobber them because it outputs a `matrix` where all variables are converted to either `character` or `numeric`. Building upon the code of Fremzy and Anthony Simon Mielniczuk you can loop through the columns of your data.frame and trim the white space off only columns of class `factor` or `character` (and maintain your data classes):

```
for (i in names(mydata)) {
  if(class(mydata[, i]) %in% c("factor", "character")){
    mydata[, i] <- trimws(mydata[, i])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that a simple approach with sapply, also works, given a df like:

```
dat<-data.frame(S=LETTERS[1:10],
            M=LETTERS[11:20],
            X=c(rep("A:A",3),"?","A:A ",rep("G:G",5)),
            Y=c(rep("T:T",4),"T:T ",rep("C:C",5)),
            Z=c(rep("T:T",4),"T:T ",rep("C:C",5)),
            N=c(1:3,'4 ','5 ',6:10),
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

You will notice that `dat$N` is going to become class character due to `'4 ' & '5 '` (you can check with `class(dat$N)`)

To get rid of the spaces on the numeic column simply convert to `numeric` with `as.numeric` or `as.integer`.

`dat$N<-as.numeric(dat$N)`

If you want to remove all the spaces, do:

```
dat.b<-as.data.frame(sapply(dat,trimws),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

And again use `as.numeric` on col N (ause sapply will convert it to `character`)

```
dat.b$N<-as.numeric(dat.b$N)
```