# don't get expected results using dplyr and group_by in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

Trying to summarize a data set, but it does not group the variables specified

Sample from the data set, `test2`

```
  newClientID   Month      newApp          count    app
  100           November    R              51       Other
  100           November    Tableau        58       Other
  100           October     R              12       Other
  100           October     Tableau        212      Other
  100           September   R              72       Other
  100           September   Tableau        74       Other
  100           October     SQL Assistant  11       Other
  100           September   SQL Assistant  396      Other
```

This should summarize the data

```
test3 <- test2 %>%
   group_by(newClientID, Month, app) %>%
   summarise(total = sum(count))
```

It should be like this

```
newClientID Month        app    total
100         November     Other  109
100         October      Other  235
100         September    Other  542
```

But I am getting

```
newClientID Month        app    total
100         November     Other  109
100         October      Other  224
100         September    Other  146
100         October      Other  11
100         September    Other  396
```

Why is it nor grouping the Month variable?

Comment: What do you get with `str(test2)` ?

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have different spellings (including spaces and carriage returns) in your observations? Try table(dataset$variablename) for each variable, or try a general trimws() on the dataset.

Comment: Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 2065 obs. of  5 
    variables:
      $ newClientID: chr  "02521" "02521" "02521" "03107" ...
      $ Month      : chr  "November" "October" "September" "November" ...
      $ newApp     : chr  "SQL Assistant" "SQL Assistant" "SQL Assistant" 
      "Cognos" ...
      $ count      : int  7 23 7 1 10 210 195 41 225 450 ...
      $ app        : chr  "Other" "Other" "Other" "Cognos" ...
      - attr(*, "vars")=List of 2
       ..$ : symbol newClientID
       ..$ : symbol Month
      - attr(*, "drop")= logi TRUE

Comment: Guessing you can't share data. Use the method in this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20760767/2747709 answer to clean your data, the method mentioned under Edit 2017 section

Comment: What is `unique(test2$Month)`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. The newClientID had white spaces. I did the following to fix all the columns in the data set:

```
test2<- data.frame(lapply(test2, function(x) if(class(x)=="character") trimws(x) else(x)), stringsAsFactors=F)
```