# R: Format columns of data frame to be compatible as lookup tables

Tags: r, bioinformatics, data-cleaning

I have two data.frames with wonky formatting. One is a large reference and the other is a subset that I would like to look up for pulling additional data from the reference, but formatting is difficult.

The smaller subset looks like this:

```
> head(lookup, n = 2)

      gene_id class_code nearest_ref_id
1 XLOC_001184       <NA>           <NA>
2 XLOC_001225       <NA>           <NA>


> gene_short_name
1      ORF%20Transcript_11308%7Cg.37058%20Transcript_11308%7Cm.37058%20type%3Acomplete%20len%3A195%20%28%2B%29
2 ORF%20Transcript_11347%7Cg.37236%20Transcript_11347%7Cm.37236%20type%3A5prime_partial%20len%3A87%20%28%2B%29

                    locus length coverage
1 Transcript_11308:0-1727     NA       NA
2 Transcript_11347:0-1584     NA       NA
```

And the reference looks like the following (Note: Some sequence were manually removed so that they are not too long to display here):

```
> head(refRna, n=2)
             seq_names   sequences
1 Transcript_0 len=550   GTTTTATTTGTTGTTGTTGTTGTTTTTATATGTA
2 Transcript_1 len=760   GACCACACCACTCGTCTGAATTCTCGATGTGGAA
```

There is a space in the `reference$seq_names`, a `:` in the `lookup$locus` with some extra numbers after it.

Some of the `reference$seq_names` have extra info with more spaces. For example:

```
4        Transcript_3 len=440 CDS=1-439 exon=0-440 five_prime_UTR=439-440 gene=0-440 mRNA=0-440 three_prime_UTR=0-1
```

The `Transcript_1234` bit is a unique identifier.

Ultimately I would like to retrieve the `reference$sequences` for each `lookup$locus` and append it to a new column, `lookup$sequence` or create a new data frame with only the `XLOC_1234`, `Transcript_1234` bit and the corresponding sequence. Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you provided, here I am giving you some advice/stratigies to tackle your problem. The assumption is that your data types are `data.frame`s not specialized classes such as `GenomicRanges`. (Use the function `class` to double check).

- First, you will need to clean up the column `reference$seq_names` by stripping away the extra space as you mentioned. Functions such as `gsub` and `str_replace` will be helpful. See [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760547/removing-whitespace-from-a-whole-data-frame-in-r).
- Similarly, the `lookup` data.frame needs to be cleaned up. To drop texts/numbers after `:`, The function `gsub` is your friend; you may combine it with regular expression to drop everything after a symbol of interest. For example:

  lookup$locus <- gsub("\:.*", "", lookup$locus) #replaces everything after : with empty string
- The "look-up" process you mentioned is known as a *query*. You'll need a *key* column to identify and match your smaller subset against the reference data set. The key in your `reference` appears to be the transcript ID, which you will need to extract from a longer string. Based on what you provided, one strategy is to drop everything after the space, and save as a new column. For example:

  reference$NEW_COLUMN <- gsub("\ .*", "", reference$seq_names)
- To achieve your final task, you may want to perform a join operation (see this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) for background). In R, we use the function `merge(DATAFRAME1, DATAFRAME2, by=KEY)`.