# How to replace specific values by others across the dataframe in R?

Tags: r, function, replace

A space is present in front of some of my variables, across rows and columns. I would like to replace all variables that contain a space, by the same variable without the space. I could do it for each of the variables but it is quite fastidious and I am sure there is a more elegant way of doing it.

```
df$var[df$var == " X"] <- "X"
```

I did this for each of my variables and for each of the levels of the variables. Could I write a function that automatically removes the space?

Comment: Is your answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760547/removing-whitespace-from-a-whole-data-frame-in-r ?

Comment: Please make your question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: see `?trimws()`

Comment: thank you, I found the answer in the link provided. I did not come across that before. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about it:

```r
x <- c( " x", " y", " z")
x
# [1]  " x" " y" " z"
y <- gsub("[[:space:]]", "", x) 
y  
#[1] "x" "y" "z"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the function `sapply` 
Basically, you could try something like this:
`df=sapply(df, function(x) f(x))` with `f` the function you wanna apply to all your columns; in your case something removing spaces if I understand well.

I'm not sure about the performance though. Because what you propose is not that bad,
To improve your performance in general, I'd recommand you to use `datatables` and not `dataframes` anymore (even with `dplyr`).

Hope it's gonna help you.