# R: how to access members of array loaded in dataframe elements

Tags: r, dataframe

From a csv file I loaded date into an R dataframe that looks like this:

```
> head(mydata)
  row lengthArray                         sports num_runs percent_runs
1   0           4               [24, 18, 24, 18]        0            0
2   1          10 [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]        0            0
3   2           4                   [0, 0, 0, 0]        0            0
4   3           2                         [0, 0]        0            0
5   4           2                       [18, 18]        0            0
6   5           1                            [0]        0            0
```

I can access and get the types for the integer data frames no problem, but I can't figure out how to access `sports`:

```
> class(mydata[4,3])
[1] "factor" 
>  string_factor = mydata[1,3]
> string_factor
[1] [24, 18, 24, 18]
6378 Levels: [0] [0, 0] [0, 0, 0] [0, 0, 0, 0] ... [9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]
> class(string_factor)
[1] "factor"
> string_factor_numeric = as.numeric(string_factor)
> string_factor_numeric
[1] 5181
```

I guess the best R response would be "don't do this", but this is how the data is coming, so I am wondering how I can get those numbers out of the array so that I can use them.

I should also mention that this [Convert data.frame columns from factors to characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters) gave no error message but had no effect, as the array column continued to be classed as factors.

```
UPDATE: from the comments, you can see this can get you somewhere:
mydata[,3]  <- as.character(mydata[,3])
```

However this still does not get you to an array with individually accessible elements.

Comment: Convert the sports column into character.`mydata[4,3]<-as.character(mydata[4,3])`

Comment: @user227710 thanks for the suggestion, but that had no effect 
> mydata[[1,3]<-as.character(mydata[1,3])
Error: unexpected assignment in "mydata[[1,3]<-"
>mydata[1,3]<-as.character(mydata[1,3])
> class(mydata[1,3])
[1] "factor"

Comment: `mydata[[1,3]<-` should be  `mydata[1,3]<-`

Comment: @user227710 that was a typo while transcribing, I think. Here's pasted directly:> mydata[1,3] <- as.character(mydata[1,3])
> class(mydata[1,3])
[1] "factor"

Comment: You can't make just the first row a character, you have to make the whole column character: `mydata[, 3] <- as.character(mydata[, 3])`.

Comment: Also "did not work" isn't informative. Did it give an error message? A warning message? You would also do well to give your desired outcome. Do you want to turn the numbers in `sports` into columns? Do you want to reshape the wide sports column to long?

Comment: @Gregor you are correct, I tried to make my question more descriptive. My goal is to create a column for each distinct integer and then for each row that column's value will be the number of times that particular integer appeared in the array. So yes, I do want to reshape the wide sports column to long if I understand that correctly.

Comment: @sunny: You should follow the advice of Gregor. It must work.

Comment: @user227710 it did work, you are correct.

Comment: @user227710 this in some ways leads me to another puzzle because this character type because now I have > f = mydata[1,3]
> f
[1] "[{u'sport': 24}, {u'sport': 18}, {u'sport': 24}, {u'sport': 18}]"
> 24 %in% f
[1] FALSE
> 18 %in% f
[1] FALSE
> class(f)
[1] "character"

Comment: @user227710 I am happy to delete if it's not helpful, but I still cannot access the individual members of the array.

Comment: It's not an array, it's just a string.

Comment: @Gregor if it were a string, I should be able to access individual characters? I don't think it's just a string because the output looks funny. The as.character converted this:[24,18,24,18] to this: {u'sport': 24}, {u'sport': 18}, {u'sport': 24}, {u'sport': 18}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your data with `dput`:

```
mydata = structure(list(row = 0:5, lengthArray = c(4L, 10L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
1L), sports = structure(c(6L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("[0, 0, 0, 0]", 
"[0, 0]", "[0]", "[18, 18]", "[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]", 
"[24, 18, 24, 18]"), class = "factor"), num_runs = c(0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), percent_runs = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("row", 
"lengthArray", "sports", "num_runs", "percent_runs"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

First we convert the sports column to a character

```
mydata$sports = as.character(mydata$sports)
```

Now I'll get rid of the brackets and spaces (leaving the commas)

```
library(stringr)
mydata$sports = str_replace_all(mydata$sports, pattern = "\\[|\\]| ", "")
```

And lastly separate the sports column into multiple columns

```
library(tidyr)
mydata = separate(mydata, sports, into = paste0("sport", 1:max(mydata$lengthArray)), sep = ",", extra = "drop")

mydata
#  row lengthArray sport1 sport2 sport3 sport4 sport5 sport6 sport7 sport8 sport9 sport10 num_runs percent_runs
#1   0           4     24     18     24     18   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>        0            0
#2   1          10      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2       2        0            0
#3   2           4      0      0      0      0   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>        0            0
#4   3           2      0      0   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>        0            0
#5   4           2     18     18   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>        0            0
#6   5           1      0   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>    <NA>        0            0
```

Comment: It's also fine to store a list as a column in a data.frame - e.g. - `mydata$sports <- strsplit(gsub("^\\[|\\]$","",as.character(mydata$sports)),", |\\[|\\]")` - which you can then access subcomponents of.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another idea using `splitstackshape`:

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% 
  mutate(sports = gsub("\\[|\\]", "", sports)) %>%
  cSplit("sports", sep = ",", direction = "wide")
```

Which gives:

```
   row lengthArray num_runs percent_runs sports_01 sports_02 sports_03 sports_04 sports_05 sports_06 sports_07 sports_08 sports_09 sports_10
1:   0           4        0            0        24        18        24        18        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
2:   1          10        0            0         2         2         2         2         2         2         2         2         2         2
3:   2           4        0            0         0         0         0         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
4:   3           2        0            0         0         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
5:   4           2        0            0        18        18        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
6:   5           1        0            0         0        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA
```

Or as per @thelatemail comment, you could also store a list as a column:

```
library(stringi)
df <- mydata %>%
  mutate(sports = as.list(stri_extract_all(sports, regex = "[:digit:]")))
```

Which will give you the following data structure:

```
> str(df)
#'data.frame':  6 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ row         : int  0 1 2 3 4 5
# $ lengthArray : int  4 10 4 2 2 1
# $ sports      :List of 6
#  ..$ : chr  "2" "4" "1" "8" ...
#  ..$ : chr  "2" "2" "2" "2" ...
#  ..$ : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0"
#  ..$ : chr  "0" "0"
#  ..$ : chr  "1" "8" "1" "8"
#  ..$ : chr "0"
# $ num_runs    : int  0 0 0 0 0 0
# $ percent_runs: int  0 0 0 0 0 0
```

You can then access the elements of the list like this:

```
> df$sports[[1]][1] #first element of first list
#[1] "2"
```

Answer (score 0):

Recreating your data:

```
text = "
row lengthArray                            sports num_runs percent_runs
   0           4               '[24, 18, 24, 18]'        0            0
   1          10 '[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]'        0            0
   2           4                   '[0, 0, 0, 0]'        0            0
   3           2                         '[0, 0]'        0            0
   4           2                       '[18, 18]'        0            0
   5           1                            '[0]'        0            0"

data <- read.table(text = text, header= TRUE)
```

You probably shoud take the values in sports and create new columns... but, if want to create the vectors inside the `sports` column, you can actually do that:

```
data$sports <- as.character(data$sports)
data$sports <- lapply(data$sports, function(x) eval(parse(text = paste0("c(", gsub("\\[|\\]", "", x),")"))))
```

Now, for example, if you want to get the third value of the first line of `sports`:

```
data$sports[[1]][[3]]
[1] 24
```