# Extract the level from a factor

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have a factor `instrumentF`:

```
> instrumentF
[1] Guitar Drums  Cello  Harp  
Levels: Cello Drums Guitar Harp
```

Let's say I extract one level of this factor using `[]`.

```
> level2 = instrumentF[1]
> level2
[1] Guitar
Levels: Cello Drums Guitar Harp
```

How I can get the factor label `Guitar` from the factor object `level2`?

`level2$level` doesn't seem to work:

```
> Error in level2$level : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: `levels(f)[levels(f)==4]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Convert to character, see this example:

```
# factor variable example
instrumentF <- as.factor(c("Guitar", "Drums", "Cello", "Harp"))

instrumentF
# [1] Guitar Drums  Cello  Harp  
# Levels: Cello Drums Guitar Harp

as.character(instrumentF)[ 1 ]
# [1] "Guitar"
```

See relevant post: [Convert data.frame columns from factors to characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters)

Or subset the level:

```
# as levels are sorted alphabetically, we need to subset the 3rd one
levels(instrumentF)[ 3 ]
# [1] "Guitar"
```