# Transfer a vector to a list

Tags: r

I have a thing which shouldn't be hard but I somehow cant crack. I have a data frame column `website_addresses` and I want to use these values as input for a function.

If i have a list like

```
list <- c("apple", "banana")
```

and try the function it works

```
fetch_function(list)
```

If however I try to input the `websiteaddresses` from the data.frame it doesn't work

```
fetch_function(df$website_addresses)
```

Gives me:

> Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : 
>        no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "factor"

I assume I have to make a list of `df$website_addresses` but cant find how to do this. Am I overlooking something really easy?

Comment: What is `fetch_function`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your website_addresses column is stored as a factor instead of strings. Pass the stringsAsFactors = FALSE argument to your data.frame when you construct it to stop this.

Alternatively put options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE) at the top of your script.

Or check this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters) explaining how to convert a column from factors to strings.