# Delete data based on string match - R

Tags: r, loops, csv, data-manipulation

I am programming in R to work on Csv and data manipulation I am trying to insert nulls if there is a match to a string in my csv.

My CSV is as follows:

```
    first_name  last _name zip_code
    Ben         Smith      12345
    Blank       Johnson    23456
    Carrie      No         34567
```

The list of bad_names that I would like to look through my csv is bad_names <- c("blank", "no","bad", "old")

Once I loop through my csv looking for the bad_name string matches, I want the output to be

```
    first_name  last _name zip_code
    Ben         Smith      12345
               Johnson    23456
    Carrie                 34567
```

So it doesn't delete the entire row, but just that matched. I am struggling with deleting just the entry, not the entire row, and looping through the entire list of bad_names.

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: Try: df$first_name[df$first_name %in% bad_names] <- ''

Comment: You may need to use 'tolower()' on the first_name column if you have case sensitivity problem.

Comment: Actually, if you have factors there, the above offered method won't work. Not to mention this is only for one column. Maybe add a `dput`

Comment: It probably makes more sense to use `NA` than an empty string, and likely `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `read.csv()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option with regex match:

With this data (youre example has an error in the `last _name` header):

```
data<-read.table(text="first_name last_name zip_code
Ben         Smith      12345
Blank       Johnson    23456
Carrie      No         34567",header=TRUE)
```

Note: I didn't use stringAsFactors=FALSE to show how I manage it if it's a factor, if it's not, get rid of the sapply call

```
bad_names <- c("blank", "no","bad", "old")
pat=paste0("(?i)\\b",paste0(bad_names,collapse="\\b|\\b"),"\\b")
t<-sapply(data,as.character)
gsub(pat,'',t)
```

I do the transition from factor to character with `sapply`, quick and dirty as it convert all to character, there's [better approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters).

The trick here is the regex construction using paste0, we create an alternation of the bad_words (separated by `|`) and surround them with `\\b` to be sure it's the whole word being matched an not just part of any word.

Then we globally substitute (`gsub`) any match by nothing.

Which gives:

```
     first_name last_name zip_code
[1,] "Ben"      "Smith"   "12345" 
[2,] ""         "Johnson" "23456" 
[3,] "Carrie"   ""        "34567"
```

This works as is as the whole data.frame is of class character, if you wish to mix them you'll have to do it a little differently (not copying again the pattern construction here):

```
f<-sapply(data,is.character)
data[,f]<-lapply(data[,f],gsub,pattern=pat,replacement='')
```

The idea is to find the column being character and apply gsub on their values to replace with empty on match.

Comment: That is perfect @Tensibai!  Thank you so much for your help!