# Using anonymous-function in data.table to change character class

Tags: r, data.table, anonymous-function

I am writing an anonymous function to loop through a data.table and change any factor variable to a character. I tried the code below, but I receive an error. My actual data.table could have a factor variable in any order, hence why I'm using lapply. Also please share any other ways to do this, but I would like my way answered as well and thanks.

```
test <- sample[, lapply(.SD, function(x){ 
  if(is.factor(x)){
    as.character(x)}
})
]


sample <- data.table(A = as.factor(1:5), B = as.character(letters[1:5]), C = as.factor(10:14))
```

Comment: You have no column named 'x'.

Comment: You can use `busTrans[, lapply(.SD, function(x) {..`

Comment: You might need to use '.SD'?

Comment: You can use `busTrans[, lapply(.SD, function(x) {..`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert data.frame columns from factors to characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters)

Answer (score 1):

You can't refer to x until you've declared it in `function(x)`

```
sample[,lapply(.SD, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) as.character(x) else x)]
```

You don't even need to use data.table syntax:

```
data.frame(lapply(sample, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) as.character(x) else x))

  A B  C
1 1 a 10
2 2 b 11
3 3 c 12
4 4 d 13
5 5 e 14
```

Comment: I get this error message now: Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'