# Filtering one dataframe by names in another dataframe while maintaining multiple categories

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two dataframes and would like to filter the `animals` column in `table1` by the `animals` column in `table2`, while retaining the multiple categories of animals in `table1` for cat and dog. The end result should appear the same as `table1`, but with "lion" removed. There should still be two "cat" and two "dog".

I'm not sure how to approach this as an r newbie. I have a feeling the answer involves the `match` function or some type of join? I would prefer a `dplyr` or `reshape2` method if possible, especially if there's a way to use a `dplyr` join function. I'm also not very experienced with the `merge` base function.

Here is the code for the two data frames:

```
table1 <- data.frame(id=c(1:7), animal=c("cat","cat","dog","dog","parakeet","lion","duck"))

table2 <- data.frame(id=c(1:4), animal=c("cat","dog","parakeet","duck"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with `semi_join` in dplyr, which will

```
      return all rows from ‘x’ where there are matching
      values in ‘y’, keeping just columns from ‘x’.

      A semi join differs from an inner join because an inner join
      will return one row of ‘x’ for each matching row of ‘y’,
      where a semi join will never duplicate rows of ‘x’.
```

But **first**, convert your data so the columns that look like strings (but are actually factors) are *actually* strings. You can do this by `table1[] <- lapply(table1, as.character)` and `table2[] <- lapply(table2, as.character)`. Or, when you create a data.frame, by

```
table1 <- data.frame(id=c(1:7), animal=c("cat","cat","dog","dog","parakeet","lion","duck"),
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
table2 <- data.frame(id=c(1:4), animal=c("cat","dog","parakeet","duck"),
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then, you can do

```
library(dplyr)
semi_join(table1, table2, by = "animal")
```

giving

```
  id   animal
1  1      cat
2  2      cat
3  3      dog
4  4      dog
5  5 parakeet
6  7     duck
```

If you don't do this (i.e., if you do join on a factor) the code will give a **warning** because `table1` and `table2` have factors, not strings. This warning shouldn't be ignored because on some versions of dplyr the coercion to characters is inconsistent. Before using `*join` functions in `dplyr`, convert your data.frame factor columns to characters.

**ps**

You could also use `%in` within `filter` to give the same result `table1 %>% filter(animal %in% table2$animal)`

Comment: `semi_join` gives me inconsistent results here (i.e. actually a different result when running the code a second time), but never the desired ones that it seems like it should...buggy, it seems.

Comment: Inconsistent between invocations on the same data or ...?

Comment: Yep. I updated a couple other packages in between, but that's the only change. There's some sort of issue here.

Comment: Hmm, looks like inconsistent factor leveling. Converting to factor manually before the join fixes the issue...but take heed of that warning.

Comment: Say, if you do have a reproducible example of inconsistent results, possibly worth filing an issue. It seems dplyr folks are trying to get consistent behavior despite the warning https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/594

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the dplyr filter() method. I don't fully understand the issue with the semi_join. I had actually tried that before asking the question and it was not giving me what I wanted. It was only outputting "cat","cat","dog","dog". So what exactly should I do to make it work? Do I convert the factors to strings?

Comment: Yes, if you create (or read in using `read.table`) the data.frame, pass the argument `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` as in the answer or [follow this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters?rq=1) to change an existing column.  Also, the inconsistency you experienced is a maybe a bug. Another commenter filed this issue:  https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/1773

Answer (score 4):

you can simply use `%in%` like this :

```
table1[table1$animal %in% table2$animal,]

  id   animal
1  1      cat
2  2      cat
3  3      dog
4  4      dog
5  5 parakeet
7  7     duck
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(table1)[table2[-1], on = "animal"]
#   id   animal
#1:  1      cat
#2:  2      cat
#3:  3      dog
#4:  4      dog
#5:  5 parakeet
#6:  7     duck
```