# R: factor changes its elements as soon as turned into column

Tags: r, object, transformation, element

I have a ridiculous problem: A factor simply changes its elements whenever I turn it into a column and use `cbind`. The factor looks like this:

```
    > bek_rec
  [1] 4 3 4 2 2 3 4 4 3 3 5 3 4 4 3 4 4 4 4 3 3 4 2 3 4 4 4 3 4 4 4
  [32] 4 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 3 3 3 4 4 3 4 4 4 4 3 4 4 3 3 4 4 4 4 3 4 5 5
  [63] 3 3 4 3 3 3 (...)
```

As soon as I use `cbind(bek_rec)`, it looks like this:

```
    > cbind(bek_rec)
   bek_rec
   [1,]       3
   [2,]       2
   [3,]       3
   [4,]       1
   [5,]       1
   [6,]       2
   [7,]       3
   [8,]       3
   [9,]       2
  [10,]       2
  [11,]       4
  [12,]       2
  [13,]       3
  [14,]       3
  [15,]       2
  [16,]       3
```

As you can see, these are not the same elements. The same thing happens when I `cbind` it with other factors. 
One the other hand, it does **not** happen for this factor:

```
    > verw_rec
  [1] 2 2 3 2 2 3 2 4 4 5 4 2 2 3 4 3 4 4 4 4 5 3 2 2 4 3 4 4 2 3 4
  [32] 4 3 2 2 3 3

    > cbind(verw_rec)
   verw_rec
  [1,]        2
  [2,]        2
  [3,]        3
  [4,]        2
  [5,]        2
  [6,]        3
  [7,]        2
  [8,]        4
  [9,]        4
  [10,]        5
  [11,]        4
  [12,]        2
```

- `bek_rec` and `verw_rec` are both factors (same class of objects)
- no packages are loaded, but if they are (like `car`), same thing
- problem happens with `cbind`, but not, for example, with `sort(bek_rec)`
- problem remains whether I reopen RStudio after saving the workspace and after not saving it.

My factor assignment for `bek_rec`looks like this:

```
    typmed3$bek_rec <- typmed$bek;
    levels(typmed3$bek_rec) <- factor(c(2,3,3.5,4,4.5,5)) 
    bek_rec <- factor(typmed$bek)                  
    levels(bek_rec) <- factor(c(2,3,3.5,4,4.5,5))
    levels(bek_rec) <- c("2","3","3","4","4","5"). #rounds .5s down.
```

The factor assignment for `verw_rec`looks the same. I know it may be a bit redundant, but it did what it was supposed to.

Does anyone understand what's going on? I'm growing a bit desperate and am very thankful for any ideas!

Comment: From the help file `?cbind` in the details section: `[...] Any classes the inputs might have are discarded (in particular, factors are replaced by their internal codes).`

Comment: But how would I change the "internal codes"? Above I provided the code of how I assigned the factors... Or should I change the class to something other than factors?

Comment: Don't change them at all. Either convert to character cbind(as.character(bek_rec)) or don't use cbind. For example you might want to use data.frame instead.

Comment: Ah! Perfect. I don't quite get why cbind has this replacing of internal codes property and how exactly it works - but thank you very much, these are good practical solutions!

Comment: Check out [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters) two [questions/answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information)

Comment: Try to do this to your data frame: `bob[] <- lapply(bob, as.character)`, replacing `bob` by the name of your frame

Comment: Thanks! That helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the factor to numeric values before attempting the cbind.

This can be done by either reading adding `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to your `read.table()` command:

```
bek_rec[] <- lapply(bek_rec, as.character)
```

The reason you are getting odd values in your verw_rec is because you are binding the index of the factors, not the values they represent. So what we are doing with the code above is removing the factors and replacing them by their actual values.

For more information check out these two Q/A's:
[Convert data.frame columns from factors to characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters)
[How to convert a factor to an integer\numeric without a loss of information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information)

Comment: Thank you! That helps. lapply means I apply a certain command (to change all values to characters) over the entirety of my object, right? Lapply does not per se transform an object into another one, does it?

Comment: @jira `lapply` is basically a for loop which outputs a list, however as mentioned in the first link you can force your data frame(a list inside a list) to be kept in original shape by adding the `[]`. You can just look at the differend `apply` functions like they are for loops. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/lapply.html