# R, how to add an unlist (and other) function inside an apply function?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, strsplit

Context: I am working with genes and ontology, but my question concerns R script writing.

I would like to replace the GO:ID in my data frame by their corresponding terms extracted form a database.

So, this is my source data frame. it is a genes list (v1) and associated GO:ID (v2):

```
>gene_list_and_Go_ID

         V1                                                V2
2563  Gene1    GO:0003871, GO:0008270, GO:0008652, GO:0009086
2580  Gene2    GO:0003871, GO:0008270, GO:0008652, GO:0009086
12686 Gene3    GO:0003871, GO:0008270, GO:0008652, GO:0009086
14523 Gene4                GO:0004489, GO:0006555, GO:0055114
```

The request to the database looks very simple:

```
>select(GO.db, my_Go_id, "TERM", "GOID")
```

I tried the following lines to address manually the database, it worked well:

```
>my_Go_id = unlist(strsplit("GO:0008270, GO:0008652, GO:0009086", split=", "))
>select(GO.db, my_Go_id, "TERM", "GOID")

    GOID                                     TERM
1 GO:0008270                         zinc ion binding
2 GO:0008652 cellular amino acid biosynthetic process
3 GO:0009086          methionine biosynthetic process
```

My problem: I cannot make this process automatic! 
Precisely, for each row, I need to transform each string from column n°2 in my data frame to a vector in order to question the database. 
And then I need to replace the GO:ID in the data frame by the result of the request.

1/ To start, I tried to put the "unlist" function in a "apply" function to my data frame:

```
apply(gene_list_and_Go_ID,1,unlist(strsplit(gene_list_and_Go_ID[,2], split=", ")))
```

I got :

```
Error in strsplit(ok, split = ", ") : non-character argument
```

2/ Then, can I add also the request to the database inside the apply function?

3/ Finally, I do not know how to replace column n°2 by the result of the database request.

This is an example of an excepted “ideal” result:

```
         V1                                                              V2
2563  Gene1        GOID                                                TERM
                   1 GO:0008270                            zinc ion binding
                   2 GO:0008652    cellular amino acid biosynthetic process
                   3 GO:0009086             methionine biosynthetic process
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The proximate issue is that you don't call `apply` like you did. Instead of writing a function *call* as you did, you need to provide a function that will take each row/column of the array in turn as input via its first argument, so you want something like (not tested, because you don't need this)

```
apply(gene_list_and_Go_ID, 1,
      function(x) { unlist(strsplit(x[2], split=", "))})
```

However, notice that you don't need entire *rows* of `gene_list_and_Go_ID`. What you want is to work on the `V2` *column* of `gene_list_and_Go_ID`. Now also note that `strsplit` is *vectorised*, which means if you pass it a vector of length greater than 1 it will work on each element of that vector as if you'd repeatedly called `strsplit()` on each element of the vector in turn.

Consider the following:

```
df <- data.frame(V1 = paste0("Gene", 1:4),
                 V2 = c("GO:0003871, GO:0008270, GO:0008652, GO:0009086",
                        "GO:0003871, GO:0008270, GO:0008652, GO:0009086",
                        "GO:0003871, GO:0008270, GO:0008652, GO:0009086",
                        "GO:0004489, GO:0006555, GO:0055114"),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Note that `V2` needs to be a character vector --- here I used `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to stop the automatic coercion `character` -> `factor`, but you could also just use `as.character(V2)` where I have `V2` in the code below.

To run `strsplit` on each element of `V2` we could use:

```
spl <- with(df, strsplit(V2, ", "))
```

which gets us

```
> spl
[[1]]
[1] "GO:0003871" "GO:0008270" "GO:0008652" "GO:0009086"

[[2]]
[1] "GO:0003871" "GO:0008270" "GO:0008652" "GO:0009086"

[[3]]
[1] "GO:0003871" "GO:0008270" "GO:0008652" "GO:0009086"

[[4]]
[1] "GO:0004489" "GO:0006555" "GO:0055114"
```

By the look of the `select` call, this is a one shot deal - you need to call it for all rows in `df` (your `gene_list_and_Go_ID`). If so, just iterate over the elements of the list returned by `strsplit()`:

```
names(spl) <- with(df, as.character(V1))
term <- lapply(spl, function(x, db) select(db, x, "TERM", "GOID"),
               db = GO.db)
```

This will return a list where each element is the result of a call to `select` for a single gene / row of `df`.

Putting it back together you probably want:

```
out <- cbind.data.frame(Gene = rep(names(spl), each = lengths(spl)),
                        do.call("rbind", term))
```

But I can't test the last few parts as I have no idea where `select()` comes from nor what created `GO.db`

Comment: Thank you for this highly detailed answer and for your time. Many things are quite new for me (paste0, with, c and rbind, rep, lengths…). I am going to learn more about all these functions, nice!   :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, according to Gavin's answer and  his kind help, I got the right script. But there was a very important step that blocked me: convert my "gene_list_and_Go_ID" data frame second column from factors to characters. I did this to skip the "non-character argument" error from the "strsplit" function. This post helped me: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters)

So here is my starting data frame:

```
>gene_list_and_Go_ID

         V1                                                V2
2563  Gene1    GO:0003871, GO:0008270, GO:0008652, GO:0009086
2580  Gene2    GO:0003871, GO:0008270, GO:0008652, GO:0009086
12686 Gene3    GO:0003871, GO:0008270, GO:0008652, GO:0009086
14523 Gene4                GO:0004489, GO:0006555, GO:0055114
```

Next, the script.
The first new line appeared very useful (convert my df from factors to characters):

```
>gene_list_and_Go_ID <- data.frame(lapply(gene_list_and_Go_ID, as.character), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

next:

```
>V_ID <- with(gene_list_and_Go_ID, strsplit(V2, ", "))
>names(V_ID) <- with(gene_list_and_Go_ID, as.character(V1))
>terms <- lapply(V_ID, function(x, db) select(db, x, "TERM", "GOID"), db = GO.db)
```

Final output is perfect :-)  :

```
> terms
$Gene1
        GOID                        TERM
1 GO:0003871 S-methyltransferase activity
2 GO:0008270 zinc ion binding
3 GO:0008652 cellular amino acid biosynthetic process
4 GO:0009086 methionine biosynthetic process

$Gene2
... etc ...
... etc ...
```

Note, I skipped the last Gavin's suggestion:

```
out <- cbind.data.frame(Gene = rep(names(spl), each = lengths(spl)),
                    do.call("rbind", term))
```

It may be a very elegant script but I have difficulties to understand all what it does, and here is what it generates:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 16, 15
In addition: Warning message:
In rep(names(V_ID), each = lengths(V_ID)) :
  first element used of 'each' argument
```

THX