# Remove duplicates in R without converting to numeric

Tags: r, duplicates

I have 2 variables in a data frame with 300 observations.

```
$ imagelike: int 3 27 4 5370 ...
$ user: Factor w/ 24915 levels "\"0.1gr\"","\"008bla\"", ..
```

I then tried to remove the duplicates, such as `"- "` appears 2 times:

```
testclean <- data1[!duplicated(data1), ]
```

This gives me the warning message:

```
In Ops.factor(left): "-"not meaningful for factors
```

I have then converted it to a maxtrix:

```
data2 <- data.matrix(data1)
testclean2 <- data2[!duplicated(data2), ]
```

This does the trick - however - it converts the `userNames` to a numeric.

=========================================================================
I am new but I have tried looking at previous posts on this topic (including the one below) but it did not work out:

[Convert data.frame columns from factors to characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters)

Comment: This looks like a problem that may be better solved when reading in the data. Are you able to some of the raw data?

Comment: sorry, i missed a word in my comment above ;). Should of read *Are you able to **share** some of the raw data?* (say the first ten rows  / five columns ). Also, can you show how you read in the data. cheers

Comment: I suggest you improve your question by reading about [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and about [reproducible questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). You will get considerably more views (and possibly answers) if your question is structured in a way that facilitates us helping you.

Comment: @r2evans thank you for your feedback

Comment: *"I don't know the usual way of sharing data here"* ... **read the links**, they are provided for good reason. Please, it really helps. Providing links to data in the question should be avoided; providing links to data in comments is worse (easy to miss). Just give us a small and representative dataset within the question. (Sometimes it takes some effort to produce a small amount of data that triggers all of your problems; often in the course of doing this, you'll find something yourself.)

Comment: @r2evans thank you, I am learning now how to do this. I still need to learn lots of things, both with R and this forum. I will work on that :)

Answer (score 1):

Some sample data, from your image (*please don't post images of data!*):

```
data1 <- data.frame(imageLikeCount = c(3,27,4,4,16,103),
                    userName = c("\"testblabla\"", "test_00", "frenchfries", "frenchfries", "test.inc", "\"parmezan_pizza\""))
str(data1)
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ imageLikeCount: num  3 27 4 4 16 103
#  $ userName      : Factor w/ 5 levels "\"parmezan_pizza\"",..: 2 5 3 3 4 1
```

To fix the problem with factors as well as the embedded quotes:

```
data1$userName <- gsub('"', '', as.character(data1$userName))
str(data1)
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ imageLikeCount: num  3 27 4 4 16 103
#  $ userName      : chr  "testblabla" "test_00" "frenchfries" "frenchfries" ...
```

Like @DanielWinkler suggested, if you can change how the data is read-in or defined, you might choose to include `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` (this argument is accepted in many functions, including `read.csv`, `read.table`, and most `data.frame` functions including `as.data.frame` and `rbind`):

```
data1 <- data.frame(imageLikeCount = c(3,27,4,4,16,103),
                    userName = c("\"testblabla\"", "test_00", "frenchfries", "frenchfries", "test.inc", "\"parmezan_pizza\""),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(data1)
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ imageLikeCount: num  3 27 4 4 16 103
#  $ userName      : chr  "\"testblabla\"" "test_00" "frenchfries" "frenchfries" ...
```

(Note that this still has embedded quotes, so you'll still need something like `data1$userName <- gsub('"', '', data1$userName)`.)

Now, we have data that looks like this:

```
data1
#   imageLikeCount       userName
# 1              3     testblabla
# 2             27        test_00
# 3              4    frenchfries
# 4              4    frenchfries
# 5             16       test.inc
# 6            103 parmezan_pizza
```

and your need to remove duplicates works:

```
data1[! duplicated(data1), ]
#   imageLikeCount       userName
# 1              3     testblabla
# 2             27        test_00
# 3              4    frenchfries
# 5             16       test.inc
# 6            103 parmezan_pizza
```

Comment: If this satisfies your question, could you accept it (check mark to the left of the answer) and consider an up-vote? Stack Exchange etiquette directs closing a question with the best answer (can be changed in the future if needed), and if you find one or more answers particularly good, you can "up-vote" them. Both actions give gratitude, kudos, and measurable reputation points to the posters.

Answer (score -1):

Try

`data$userName <- as.character(data$userName)`

And then 
`data<-unique(data)`

You could also pass the argument `stringAsFactor = FALSE` when reading the data. This is usually a good idea.

Comment: From a glance at their screenshot,and `str`, its unlikely to be this simple. For example, `dat <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=c("word", "\"word\"", "and another"));
as.character(dat$y); length(unique(as.character(dat$y)))`

Comment: This could probably be addressed with gsub replacing ' '' ' with empty space. Something like `gsub('"', '', data$userName)`

Comment: And that should probably have been your answer rather than what you posted.

Comment: I don't see how `data[unique(data),]` would work: `unique` will return a `data.frame`, not a vector of `integer` or `logical` need for row-indexing. Similar to the suggestion to the OP, can you please **provide sample data** to support your code?