# R: not extracting right columns from table

Tags: r

I am a beginner in R. I have a table that looks like this:

```
> means
        as  er op rt
a 34.66667 3.5 87  4
b 22.66667 4.5  9  5
c  5.00000 7.5  6  9
d  6.00000 0.5  6  3
e  3.00000 8.0  7 89
```

and another one that looks like this:

```
> table
  exp ctrl
1  as   er
2  rt   op
```

I want to extract the values from the columns in "means" that are indicated in column "exp" of "table", like this:

```
> means_exp <- means[, table$exp]
```

In the real situation both tables would be much bigger, so I don't want to just specify the names of the columns to extract one by one.

However, with that command I am getting this:

```
> means_exp
        as  er
a 34.66667 3.5
b 22.66667 4.5
c  5.00000 7.5
d  6.00000 0.5
e  3.00000 8.0
```

but I am supposed to get columns "as" and "rt", not "as" and "er"

Any idea why the wrong columns are extracted?

Thank you!

Here is the dput of the first table:

```
structure(c(34.6666666666667, 22.6666666666667, 5, 6, 3, 3.5, 
4.5, 7.5, 0.5, 8, 87, 9, 6, 6, 7, 4, 5, 9, 3, 89), .Dim = c(5L, 
4L), .Dimnames = list(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), c("as", "er", 
"op", "rt")))
```

and that of the second:

```
structure(list(exp = structure(1:2, .Label = c("as", "rt"), class = "factor"), 
    ctrl = structure(1:2, .Label = c("er", "op"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("exp", 
"ctrl"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Try `means[,as.character(table$exp)]`

Comment: That works! Thanks. Could you explain why please?

Comment: What are the columns of `table`? Are they factors? Please inspect `str(table)` .

Comment: Ok done. 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ exp : Factor w/ 2 levels "as","rt": 1 2
 $ ctrl: Factor w/ 2 levels "er","op": 1 2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the OP got different columns with the 'exp' column in 'table' is the `class` of the `exp`.  It would be `factor` class, so converting to `character` is an option.

```
 means[,as.character(table$exp)]
```

---

The `factor` gets coerced to integer and we get

```
as.integer(factor(table$exp))
#[1] 1 2

means[,factor(table$exp)]
#       as  er
#a 34.66667 3.5
#b 22.66667 4.5
#c  5.00000 7.5
#d  6.00000 0.5
#e  3.00000 8.0
```

So, it selects the first 2 columns instead of the 'as' and 'rt'