# Data.frame in R: concatenation of two column, numbers instead of occurrences

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a very simple question, but I cannot find the answer: I have this data.frame:

```
b=c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c")
c=c("b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","d")

a<-data.frame(b,c)
```

Why if I'd like to put in one column the `a$b` and `a$c` vector with this:

```
f<-c(a$b,a$c)
```

The result is not like

```
> f<-c(b,c)
> f
 [1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "b" "c" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "c" "d"
```

but

```
> f<-c(a$b,a$c)
> f
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3
```

?
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Tried this, looking at the possible duplicate suggest above:

```
> a<-data.frame(z=as.character(b),k=as.character(c))
> f<-c(a$z,a$k)
> f  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert data.frame columns from factors to characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters)

Comment: Hi, if I am not wrong that does not work, but the solution under yes!

Comment: Basically, this is a very common problem where we consider factor as characters and try to do different operations on them.  It would also work if you do `f <- c(as.character(a$z), as.character(a$k))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set `stringsAsFactors` to `FALSE` in the `data.frame()` function. Otherwise the strings are interpreted as factors, resulting in your undesired output.

```
b <- c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","c")
c <- c("b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","d")

a <- data.frame(b,c, stringsAsFactors = F)

f <- c(a$b,a$c)

f
[1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "b" "c" "b" "b" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "c" "d"
```