# convert to date in R using abbreviated month

Tags: r, as.date

I'm new to R and trying to load some time series data but I'm stuck at the first hurdle.

I have a dataframe with a date column called `Date`. The date format of the data is: `23-May-16` (it appears like this in the R console when I print `df`). To read as date I'm trying:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(df$Date, "%dd-%bbb-%yy")
```

as per guidance [here](http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html)

which produces the value `<NA>` when it reads the data.

Comment: is "df$Date" a `character`? Try `str(df)` ?

Comment: apparently `df$Date` is a factor... `ï..Date: Factor w/ 251 levels`

Comment: may be the first thing is to convet the factor to char first.  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters#2851213). You can do `options(stringsAsFactors=FALSE)` and reread your `data.frame` as well. Then @agerom solution seems fine. Cheers!

Comment: You are just using the wrong format and you should really read the docs of `?as.Date` or `?strptime` which have similar examples. factors have nothing to do with this.

Comment: `df$Date <- as.character.Date(df$Date)` or use `strptime` or the package `anytime` and list goes on and on. Or you can provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

`as.Date(df$Date,format="%d-%b-%y")`

Comment: glad it helps. As a separate note bear in mind that 'lubridate' package's magic. Give it a shot

Answer (score 0):

You only need to list those once:

```
as.Date("23-May-16", "%d-%b-%y")
```