# converting the variable datatype

Tags: r, optimization

I have a data frame with 25 variables.

I would like to convert the columns 2:8 ; 10:17 ; 24:25 as numeric.

I am using a separate  for loops to convert the data type. Is there a way, i could use a single for loop and convert them to numeric.

Also, I wanted to convert 9, 18 in date format.

It would be helpful, if you could help me to minimise my code to single for loop

```
for (i in 2:8){
  claim[,i] <- as.numeric(claim[,i])
}

for(i in 10:17){
  claim[,i] <- as.numeric(claim[,i])
}

for(i in 24:25){
  claim[,i] <- as.numeric(claim[,i])
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one row code:

```
claim[,c(2:8,10:17,24:25)] <- lapply(claim[,c(2:8,10:17,24:25)], as.numeric)
```

Adaptation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters) answer.

The same could be done with `date` convertion:

```
claim[,c(9,18)] <- lapply(claim[,c(9,18)], as.Date)
```

Comment: Yes it's true, It was redundant. Edited, thank you.

Comment: getting an error undefined columns selected

Comment: Please add a sample of your dataframe. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: It worked and I have accepted it as answer

Answer (score 0):

This is not super efficient, but the first thing that comes to mind is defining a vector that contains the indices that you want to transform, and then iterating across it like this:

```
indices <- c(2:8, 10:17, 24:25)

for(i in indices) {
  claim[,i] <- as.numeric(claim[,i])
}
```