# R: factor to character does not work

Tags: r, string, dataframe, character

I just do not understand why my data frame keeps being a factor even if I try to change it to a character.

Here I have a data frame `list_attribute$affrete`.

```
affrete
<chr>
Fruits
Apple                
Grape Fruits             
Lemon                
Peach                
Banana               
Orange               
Strawberry               
Apple
```

And I applied a function to replace some values in `list_attribute$affrete` to other values using another data frame `renaming`, which has two columns(Name and Rename).

```
affrete <- plyr::mapvalues(x = unlist(list_attribute$affrete, use.names = F), 
                           from = as.character(renaming$Name), 
                           to = as.character(renaming$Rename))
affrete <- as.character(affrete)
list_attribute$affrete <- data.frame(affrete)
```

The data frame `renaming` looks like this;

```
 Name        Rename
 <fctr>      <fctr>
 Apple       Manzana          
 Orange      Naranja          
 Lemon       Limon            
 Grape       Uva          
 Peach       Melocoton            
 Pinapple    Anana
```

And here is `list_attribute$affrete` after applying these processes above.

```
affrete
<fctr>
Manzana                
Grape Fruits             
Limon                
Melocoton                
Banana               
Naranja               
Strawberry               
Manzana
```

Why is this column still a factor? I tried the method discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters/2853231) but none of them works. WHY? I'd appreciate for any help!

Comment: Not sure why you `unlist` the character vector `list_attribute$affrete`. Based on what you said the output of `plyr::mapvalues` should be a character vector as well. No need to do `as.character(affrete)` and `data.frame(affrete)`. Try this as an example `library(plyr);

x <- c("a", "b", "c");
x1 = factor(c("a", "c"));
x2 = factor(c("A", "C"));

mapvalues(x, as.character(x1), as.character(x2))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default `data.frame` has argument `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`. When you call `data.frame(affrete)` it converts characters to factors. You can either:

1. Call `data.frame(affrete, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` instead
2. Set this behaviour off permanently for your session with `options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`
3. Fix after the fact once it's already in the list with `list_attribute$affrete$affrete <- as.character(list_attribute$affrete$affrete)`
4. Use `tbls` from the `tidyverse`, so call `tibble(affrete)` instead. These never convert characters, among other benefits.

Comment: thank you! I chose 1st one but all the methods worked.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is from `list_attribute$affrete <- data.frame(affrete)`, the default behavior of `data.frame()` is with `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`