# Treatment of factors when converting to character in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to convert a factor to character so that I can relevel.  The conversion works for data.frames but does not work in data.table.  I know that I can use as.character( ) to convert factors in data.frames but can't figure it out in data.table ([Convert data.frame columns from factors to characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters))

Here is an example

```
library( data.table )
mtcars$name <- as.factor( rownames( mtcars ) ) 
m <- data.table( mtcars )
```

So this is the fourth row of the factor

```
m[ 4 , "name" ]
```

when data.table converts it to character it makes it a number

```
as.character( m[ 4 , "name" ] )
```

It works in a data.frame - this is what I want

```
as.character( mtcars[ 4 , "name" ] )
```

I need to get this to work so I can relevel the factor.  I want to specify which is the reference category by name

```
m <- within(m, name <- relevel(name, ref = as.character( m[ 4 , "name" ]) ))
```

It works with a data.frame

```
mtcars <- within(mtcars, name <- relevel(name, ref = as.character( mtcars[ 4 , "name" ]) ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the column, it is still a `data.table` with one column

```
as.character(m[4, "name"]$name)
#[1] "Hornet 4 Drive"
```

---

The issue is that the column is 1) `factor`, 2), it is still a data.table (subsetting of `data.frame` behavior is different as it has `drop = TRUE` as default behavior, here it is not the case)

We can replicate the same issue with `data.frame` too

```
as.character(mtcars[4, "name", drop = FALSE])
#[1] "13"
```

`factor`s are coerced to `integer` storage mode values and then only it gets converted to `character`