# Converting three variables in a dataframe from chr to int in R

Tags: r, integer, character

Very new to R but I'm hoping this will be simple. I have a html table I scraped into R and it looks like this:

```
`'data.frame':  238 obs. of  6 variables:
$ Facility Name      : chr  "Affinity Healthcare Center"     "Alameda Care Center" "Alcott Rehabilitation Hospital" "Alden Terrace Convalescent Hospital" ...
$ City               : chr  "Paramount" "Burbank" "Los Angeles" "Los Angeles" ...
$ State              : chr  " CA" " CA" " CA" " CA" ...
$ Confirmed Staff    : chr  "26" "36" "14" "27" ...
$ Confirmed Residents: chr  "29" "49" "26" "85" ...
$ Total Deaths       : chr  26 36 14 27 19 3 1 7 16 3 ...`
```

I want `Confirmed Staff`, `Confirmed Residents` and `Total Deaths` to be integers so I can do some math on them and sort, order, etc.

I tried this for one variable and it seemed to work ok:

```
`tbls_ls4$`Total Deaths` <- as.integer(tbls_ls4$`Confirmed Staff`)`
```

But I'd like to apply it to all three variables and not sure how to do that.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have `factors` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert data.frame columns from factors to characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters)

Comment: `lapply(df,as.integer)` or `dplyr::mutate(across(is.character,~as.integer)`

Comment: Be aware that `across` is only available in development versions of `dplyr`.

Comment: @NelsonGon: I was asking @jkandel, if he/she knew that `factor` variables allow sorting/ordering etc. without loosing the information about label. I think that, given the question, `factors` are better for the first two variables

Answer (score 2):

Several ways to do that:

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
cols <- c("Confirmed Staff", "Confirmed Residents", "Total Deaths")
df[,cols := lapply(.SD, as.integer),.SDcols = cols]
```

or if you prefer base `R` :

```r
df[, cols] <- lapply(cols, function(d) as.integer(df[,d]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `mutate_at` from the `tidyverse` package to convert certain columns from character to integer.

```
library(tidyverse)

df<-df %>%
  # Indicate the column names you wish to convert inside vars
  mutate_at(vars(ConfirmedStaff,ConfirmedResidents,TotalDeaths),
            # Indicate the function to apply to each column
            as.integer)
```