# Convert entire data frame to character class with R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to convert all columns in the mtcars data frame into the class type "character".

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>% mutate_all(as.character())
#> # A tibble: 32 x 11
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#>  2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#>  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#>  4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#>  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#>  6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
#>  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
#>  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#>  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#> 10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

My attempt doesn't even mutate a single column to class "character". Hmmmm... how do I mutate all columns into class "character"? I would like to avoid *apply and loops [as these types of popular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851015/convert-data-frame-columns-from-factors-to-characters) solutions suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just don't need the `()` as it returns `character(0)` because it expects an argument in the invocation process.  The function expression is evaluated, but the argument expression is empty resulting in a zero length output as the value of the invocation expression

```
as.character()
#character(0)

library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
     as_tibble() %>% 
     mutate_all(as.character)
```

and this has the same effect as

```
mtcars %>%
      as_tibble %>%
      mutate_all(character(0))
```

In the newer versions, use `mutate` with `across`

```
mtcars %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), as.character))
```

If we are using `as.character()` use it with anonymous function call

```
mtcars %>%
     as_tibble() %>% 
     mutate_all(~ as.character(.))
```